# Asynchronously read stdout from subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I am running a sub-program using subprocess.popen.  When I start my Python program from the command window (cmd.exe), the program writes some info and dates in the window as the program evolves.

When I run my Python code *not* in a command window, it opens a new command window for this sub-program's output, and I want to avoid that.  When I used the following code, it doesn't show the cmd window, but it also doesn't print the status:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("c:/flow/flow.exe", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print p.stdout.read()
```

How can I show the sub-program's output in my program's output as it occurs?

Comment: "windows window" What Windows window? Are you using a GUI framework? Which one?

Comment: well, i am running the model through arcgis. when i click my tool i created over there, a window comes through and shows the progress. I  want to see lines appearing in my command window.

Comment: And, sorry about the wiki. I didn't meat to click that option.

Comment: python3 w/ asyncio this is what you want: https://kevinmccarthy.org/2016/07/25/streaming-subprocess-stdin-and-stdout-with-asyncio-in-python/

Answer (score 7):

Use this:

```
cmd = subprocess.Popen(["c:/flow/flow.exe"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in cmd.stdout:
    print line.rstrip("\n")
cmd.wait()  # you may already be handling this in your current code
```

Note that you will still have to wait for the sub-program to flush its stdout buffer (which is commonly buffered differently when not writing to a terminal window), so you may not see each line instantaneously as the sub-program prints it (this depends on various OS details and details of the sub-program).

Also notice how I've removed the shell=True and replaced the string argument with a list, which is generally recommended.

Comment: alternatively to the 'line.rstrip..' you can use 'line,' (note the trailing comma)

Comment: [`for line in iter(cmd.stdout.readline, ""): print line,`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804543/read-subprocess-stdout-line-by-line) might provide a more immediate output by possibly avoiding read-ahead buffer in the file iterator (note: the sub-program still have to flush its stdout)

Comment: Don't see why this is async.

Answer (score 2):

Looking for a recipe to process Popen data asynchronously I stumbled upon http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576759-subprocess-with-async-io-pipes-class/

This looks quite promising, however I got the impression that there might be some typos in it.  Not tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

It is an old post, but a common problem with a hard to find solution. Try this: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/440554-module-to-allow-asynchronous-subprocess-use-on-win/

Comment: Unfortunately this solution there isn't asynchronous.