# real time subprocess.Popen via stdout and PIPE

Tags: python, logging, subprocess, pipe, popen

I am trying to grab `stdout` from a `subprocess.Popen` call and although I am achieving this easily by doing:

```
cmd = subprocess.Popen('ls -l', shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
for line in cmd.stdout.readlines():
    print line
```

I would like to grab `stdout` in "real time". With the above method, PIPE is waiting to grab all the `stdout` and then it returns.

So for logging purposes, this doesn't meet my requirements (e.g. "see" what is going on while it happens).

Is there a way to get line by line, `stdout` while is running? Or is this a limitation of `subprocess`(having to wait until the `PIPE` closes).

*EDIT*
If I switch `readlines()` for `readline()` I only get the last line of the `stdout` (not ideal):

```
In [75]: cmd = Popen('ls -l', shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
In [76]: for i in cmd.stdout.readline(): print i
....: 
t
o
t
a
l

1
0
4
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822237/writing-the-command-window-to-the-windows-while-running-an-exe-in-python

Comment: related: [Python: read streaming input from subprocess.communicate()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2715847/4279)

Comment: With `readline()`, you get the first line, not the last line. You have to repeatedly call `readline()` to get every line.

Comment: related: [Python subprocess readlines() hangs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12419198/4279)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your interpreter is buffering. Add a call to sys.stdout.flush() after your print statement.

Comment: @alfredodeza: it can't possibly work `.readlines()` won't return until *all output* is read (until EOF happens) and therefore adding `sys.stdout.flush()` won't change anything. It contradicts your requirement: *"Is there a way to get line by line, stdout while [the child process] is running?"*

Answer (score 19):

Actually, the real solution is to directly redirect the stdout of the subprocess to the stdout of your process.

Indeed, with your solution, you can only print stdout, and not stderr, for instance, at the same time.

```
import sys
from subprocess import Popen
Popen("./slow_cmd_output.sh", stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr).communicate()
```

The `communicate()` is so to make the call blocking until the end of the subprocess, else it would directly go to the next line and your program might terminate before the subprocess (although the redirection to your stdout will still work, even after your python script has closed, I tested it).

That way, for instance, you are redirecting both stdout and stderr, and in absolute real time.

For instance, in my case I tested with this script `slow_cmd_output.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6; do sleep 5 && echo "${i}th output" && echo "err output num ${i}" >&2; done
```

Comment: Note: I know the thread is old, but I came across this thread and the answer did not satisfy me. Having found the answer, I thought I might as well post it :)

Comment: Are there any pitfalls for this? @Undo

Comment: this gave me an `UnsupportedOperation` error

Answer (score 11):

To get output "in real time", `subprocess` is unsuitable because it can't defeat the other process's buffering strategies.  That's the reason I always recommend, whenever such "real time" output grabbing is desired (quite a frequent question on stack overflow!), to use instead [pexpect](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect) (everywhere but Windows -- on Windows, [wexpect](http://wstein.org/home/goreckc/sage/wexpect/)).

Comment: Expect's line buffering is a topic (recently) dear to my heart; would you mind having a look at my latest question?

Comment: @Tobu, sure, had a look and answered (recommending pexpect again).

Comment: Also [`winpexpect` module](https://bitbucket.org/geertj/winpexpect/overview) could be used on Windows.

Comment: you could also [provide a pseudo-tty even while using `subprocess` module](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12471855/4279)

Answer (score 3):

Drop the readlines() which is coalescing the output.
Also you'll need to enforce line buffering since most commands will interally buffer output to a pipe. For details see: http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/

Comment: I went through the link but I am not clear how to enforce buffering in Python, would you be able to clarify?

Comment: You enforce buffering on the command. tail -f line buffers by default. For grep, sed etc. you'll need to pass appropriate options to them. Note also the new stdbuf command which can apply line buffering to any command that uses stdio

Answer (score 3):

As this is a question I searched for an answer to for days, I wanted to leave this here for those who follow.  While it is true that `subprocess` cannot combat the other process's buffering strategy, in the case where you are calling another Python script with `subprocess.Popen`, you CAN tell it to start an unbuffered python.

```
command = ["python", "-u", "python_file.py"]
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
    line = line.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '')
    print line
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

I have also seen cases where the popen arguments `bufsize=1` and `universal_newlines=True` have helped with exposing the hidden `stdout`.

Comment: you could use `print line,` (note: comma) to avoid stripping newlines (no need `replace('\n','')` or `rstrip(b'\r\n')`).

Answer (score 1):

```
cmd = subprocess.Popen(["ls", "-l"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in cmd.stdout:
    print line.rstrip("\n")
```

Comment: Roger, this is still waiting for the process to end. The way I can confirm this is happening, is by running a longer process like a system update and passing the information to the log. All lines in a 10 second running process are printed/written to the log at the same time

Comment: You're running into a buffer size problem; take my above code and change the command to `["find", "/"]` and you will see output before that process ends.

Comment: I `print(line.rstrip("\n"))` and got `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` in Python3, do you have some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The call to `readlines` is waiting for the process to exit. Replace this with a loop around `cmd.stdout.readline()` (note singular) and all should be well.

Comment: ths just returns the last line, not all the lines:

    for i in cmd.stdout.readline(): print i
   ....: 
 t
 o
 t
 a
 l
 
 1
 0
 4

Comment: Yes, my bad. The correct answer is the one by Robert Pate above.

Comment: There is answer by Robert Pate (at least search for Robert find nothing). And while your answer is not correct, you should delete it...

Answer (score 0):

As stated already the issue is in the stdio library's buffering of printf like statements when no terminal is attached to the process. There is a way around this on the Windows platform anyway. There may be a similar solution on other platforms as well.

On Windows you can force create a new console at process creation. The good thing is this can remain hidden so you never see it (this is done by shell=True inside the subprocess module).

```
cmd = subprocess.Popen('ls -l', shell=True, stdout=PIPE, creationflags=_winapi.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)
for line in cmd.stdout.readlines():
    print line
```

or

A slightly more complete solution is that you explicitly set the STARTUPINFO params which prevents launching a new and unnecessary cmd.exe shell process which shell=True did above.

```
class PopenBackground(subprocess.Popen):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        si = kwargs.get('startupinfo', subprocess.STARTUPINFO())
        si.dwFlags |= _winapi.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
        si.wShowWindow = _winapi.SW_HIDE

        kwargs['startupinfo'] = si
        kwargs['creationflags'] = kwargs.get('creationflags', 0) | _winapi.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
        kwargs['bufsize'] = 1
        kwargs['universal_newlines'] = True

        super(PopenBackground, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

process = PopenBackground(['ls', '-l'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    for line in cmd.stdout.readlines():
        print line
```

Comment: child's buffering strategy does not matter as long as you use `.readlines()` that does not return until EOF. Use `for line in iter(cmd.stdout.readline, b''):` instead. [Read my answers to the questions I've linked above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082850/real-time-subprocess-popen-via-stdout-and-pipe/32538935#comment29502226_2082850)