# Python PIPE to popen stdin

Tags: python, popen

I am attempting something very similar to [real time subprocess.Popen via stdout and PIPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082850/real-time-subprocess-popen-via-stdout-and-pipe)

I, however, want to send input to the running process as well.

If I start a process in a separate thread using

```
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

I can send input using the terminal.

How would I send input from another source such as separate function not in the thread?

I cannot use `Popen.communicate` as the running process will never finish, as I am attempting real time interaction with the program.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my complete code, I am looking to have input sent to the subprocoess process when the send button is clicked.

```
from Tkinter import *`
from ttk import *`
import subprocess
from threading import Thread

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
       Frame.__init__(self, parent)   

        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):    

        self.parent.title("Test Client")
        self.style = Style()
        self.style.theme_use("default")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        #Label, doesnt change
        lbl = Label(self, text="Client:")
        lbl.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W )

        #when output from client is shown
        global display
        display = Text(self,width=50,height=20)
        display.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=E+W+N+S)

        #where user input is taken
        global prompt
        prompt = Entry(self,width=50)
        prompt.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=E+W+N+S)

        #Button that will send input to client
        send = Button(self,text="Send",command=self.send)
        send.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=N)
        get = Button(self,text="Get",command=self.get)
        get.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=S)

    def get(self):
        print foo

    def send(self):
        sent = prompt.get()


def MyThread():
     global sent
     sent = 2
     cmd = ['nc', '-l', '-p', '50000']

     process = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

    while True:
        out = process.stdout.read(1)
        if out == '' and process.poll() != None:
            break
        if out != '':
            display.insert(INSERT, out)
            sys.stdout.write(out)
            sys.stdout.flush()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("500x410+300+300")
    app = Example(root)

    thread = Thread(target = MyThread, args=())
    thread.start()

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You should be able to use `Popen.communicate()` for that, have you actually tried it? What happen when you do?

Comment: @LieRyan: `communicate` `wait`s for the child to finish and reads all of its output. Since "the running process will never finish", this means `communicate` will never return. So he can't use it.

Comment: you shouldn't probably call GUI from a background thread directly (it might or might not work intermittently). You could use a queue and `root.after()` to scheduler a call to GUI from the thread. Avoid using `global` unnecessarily, you could use instance variables instead e.g., `self.prompt`. You could use `socket`, `select` modules instead of running `netcat`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Good point about just using a socket directly instead of scripting `netcat`. (You'll probably still need a separate thread to service that socket… but better than 3-4 threads to service a subprocess… And a whole lot simpler. And it'll work on systems with BSD or Hobbit netcat instead of GNU netcat, or with no netcat at all. And so on.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you obviously need to add `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` to the `Popen` constructor, and then you can `process.stdin.write` just as you `process.stdout.read`.

But obviously, just as `read` can block if there's no data yet, `write` can block if the child isn't reading.

And even beyond the obvious, it's actually very hard to get the details right for using PIPEs in both directions with `Popen` to an interactive program without blocking anywhere. If you really want to do it, look at [the source for `communicate`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/subprocess.py#l881) to see how it works. (There are known bugs before 3.2, so if you're on 2.x, you may have to do some backporting.) You will have to implement the code yourself, and if you want it to be cross-platform, you're going to have to do the whole mess that `communicate` does internally (spawning reader and writer threads for the pipes, etc.), and of course add another thread to not block the main thread on each attempt to communicate, and some kind of mechanism to message the main thread when the child is ready, and so on.

Alternatively, you can look at the various "async subprocess" projects on PyPI. The simplest one I know of today is [`async_subprocess`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/async_subprocess/0.2.1), which basically just gives you a `communicate` that you can use without blocking.

Or, if you can use `twisted` (or possibly other event-based networking frameworks), there are wrappers around subprocess that plug into its event loop. (If you can wait for Python 3.4, or use the work-in-progress `tulip` on 3.3, someone's built something similar around `tulip` that may make it into 3.4.) And `twisted` even knows how to plug into `Tkinter`, so you don't have to manually handle two separate event loops and communicate between them.

If you only care about modern POSIX systems (not Windows), you can make it simpler by just putting the pipes in non-blocking mode and writing your code as if you were dealing with sockets.

But the easiest solution is probably to use something like [`pexpect`](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect) instead of trying to script it manually. (As J.F. Sebastian points out, `pexpect` is Unix-only, but you can use a wrapper around `pexpect` for Unix and [`winpexpect`](https://bitbucket.org/geertj/winpexpect/overview) for Windows.)

Comment: I have looked at communicate and because its a blocking call it will not work with the commands I wish to run, pexpect is also unusable as I am not trying to script something but have an interactive program.

Comment: @MrS: I didn't say to use `communicate`, I said you have to look at the source to see all the things you will need to deal with in order to implement this yourself. Which is not going to be easy.

Comment: @MrS: Also, who told you that `pexpect` can't be used to script an interactive program? That's kind of the whole point of it.

Comment: there is also [`winpexpect` module](https://bitbucket.org/geertj/winpexpect/overview) on Windows.

Answer (score 5):

The [select](http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html) module in the standard library is made for these kind of situation:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
   reads,writes,excs = select.select([process.stdout, process.stderr], [process.stdin], [], 1)
   for r in reads:
       out = r.read(1)
       display.insert(INSERT, out)
       sys.stdout.write(out)
       sys.stdout.flush()
   for w in writes:
       w.write('a')
```

You can pass a list of file objects or file descriptors to `select()` which will return those files that are have data ready for read/write or until an optional timeout.

The select module works on both Windows and Unix-like systems (Linux, Macs, etc).

Comment: `select` is *nix only solution (only sockets can be used on Windows i.e., `select` doesn't work on pipes there). There should be `process.poll()` call somewhere to check whether the process is complete.

Comment: It works on _most_ *nix platforms, but not all. And on some, it only works if you explicitly set the pipes to nonblocking first, which you aren't doing here.

Answer (score 0):

A simple portable solution in your case with minimal code changes might be to create a writer thread that get items from a queue and writes them to the process' stdin and then put values into the queue whenever the button is pressed:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
from Queue import Queue

class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, queue):
       # ...
       self.queue = queue
    # ...
    def send(self): # should be call on the button press
        self.queue.put(prompt.get())

def writer(input_queue, output): 
    for item in iter(input_queue.get, None): # get items until None found
        output.write(item)
    output.close()

def MyThread(queue):
    # ...
    #NOTE: you must set `stdin=PIPE` if you wan't to write to process.stdin
    process = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
    Thread(target=writer, args=[queue, process.stdin]).start()
    # ...

def main():
    # ...
    queue = Queue()
    app = Example(root, queue)
    Thread(target=MyThread, args=[queue]).start()
    # ...
    root.mainloop()
    queue.put(None) # no more input for the subprocess
```

Comment: Might be useful for someone ; for me I have to add output.flush() after output.write() to make it work

Comment: @Raj `bufsize=0` on Python 2; `output=process.stdin` and therefore `output.flush()` is useless in this case.

Comment: I am using Python 3.x. Any reason why I have to use flush()(believe buffer is getting filled up before pushed into  the stream)...not sure if there is a better way

Comment: Both the question and my answer use Python 2. On Python 3, the default is different `bufsize=-1` (block buffered mode) and `output.flush()` could be useful. There are other changes on Python 3 e.g., text vs. binary mode.