# Popen freeze / PySide GUI / cmd popup

Tags: python, user-interface, cmd, pyside

I'm creating a simple GUI for djv_converter: http://djv.sourceforge.net/documentation.html
It's working fine but I lack some feedback from this app when I run it with Popen.

```
args =  [djv_path, newout, "%smov" % moviename,"-speed", speed ,"-scale", scale, "-save",    "quicktime",  "quality", quality, "-save", "quicktime",  "codec", codec, "-channel", channel]

child = subprocess.Popen(args,stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Normally the application outputs some progress to the console which I would like to use to update my progress bar.

The issue is that any kind of stdout happens after the process is finished. It looks as if it freezes at the point of creating a child process and then unfreezes when it's done. I've tried both with **communicate** and **child.stdout.read** and the same thing happens.

I run my python code from a bat file that is called from the registry, so I can have it under my right click menu. The GUI is written in PySide.

I also can't stop the popup of the cmd window, whether it is pythonw and .pyw file or modified .bat file.

If anyone knows what may be causing the problems please let me know :)

Thanks a lot,
KK

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is that any kind of stdout happens after the process is
>   finished.

`subprocess.Popen` is not displaying the STDOUT until the buffer is full.  In your case, the buffer never fills, so nothing is displayed until the subprocess is completed.

Might I point you to this thread with some suggested recommendations:
[real time subprocess.Popen via stdout and PIPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082850/real-time-subprocess-popen-via-stdout-and-pipe/16404840#16404840)

Your milage may vary as none of the solutions seemed to be the magic bullet for anyone.  I personally found that instructing the `subprocess.Popen` to open an unbuffered Python did the trick.

```
command = ["python", "-u", "python_file.py"]
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
    line = line.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '')
    print line
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I forgot to add that I've tried flushing anything in stdout with no success. I also had gone before through the thread you recommended and none of the methods work. Or at least they work the same way: as the external program terminates, I get my output, which is no good for me.

Could it be the specific application that blocks my GUI app?

Again, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @krzykli probably a silly question, but when you run your program from the command line (not from subprocess.Popen but directly from the command line), does it pipe the output to the terminal in real-time?

Comment: Yep it does. It shows the progress of converting an image sequence to mov file every 10% or so.