# python subprocess.call output is not interleaved

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a python (v3.3) script that runs other shell scripts. My python script also prints message like "About to run script X" and "Done running script X".

When I run my script I'm getting all the output of the shell scripts separate from my print statements. I see something like this:

```
All of script X's output
All of script Y's output
All of script Z's output
About to run script X
Done running script X
About to run script Y
Done running script Y
About to run script Z
Done running script Z
```

My code that runs the shell scripts looks like this:

```
print( "running command: " + cmnd )
ret_code = subprocess.call( cmnd, shell=True )
print( "done running command")
```

I wrote a basic test script and *do* *not* see this behaviour. This code does what I would expect:

```
print("calling")
ret_code = subprocess.call("/bin/ls -la", shell=True )
print("back")
```

Any idea on why the output is not interleaved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks. This works but has one limitation - you can't see any output until after the command completes. I found an answer from another question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082850/real-time-subprocess-popen-via-stdout-and-pipe)) that uses popen but also lets me see the output in real time. Here's what I ended up with this:

```
import subprocess
import sys

cmd = ['/media/sf_git/test-automation/src/SalesVision/mswm/shell_test.sh', '4', '2']
print('running command: "{0}"'.format(cmd))  # output the command.
# Here, we join the STDERR of the application with the STDOUT of the application.
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ''):
    line = line.replace('\n', '')
    print(line)
    sys.stdout.flush()
process.wait()                   #  Wait for the underlying process to complete.
errcode = process.returncode      #  Harvest its returncode, if needed.
print( 'Script ended with return code of: ' + str(errcode) )
```

This uses Popen and allows me to see the progress of the called script.

Comment: note: on Python 3.3, you can use `for line in process.stdout:` instead of `iter(...)`. Also, you could use `print(line, end='', flush=True)` instead of `line.replace('\n',''); print(line); sys.stdout.flush()` or use `line = line.rstrip('\n')`. Call `process.stdout.close()` after the loop.

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with STDOUT and STDERR buffering. You should be using `subprocess.Popen` to redirect `STDOUT` and `STDERR` from your child process into your application. Then, as needed, output them. Example:

```
import subprocess

cmd = ['ls', '-la']
print('running command: "{0}"'.format(cmd))  # output the command.
# Here, we join the STDERR of the application with the STDOUT of the application.
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
process.wait()  # Wait for the underlying process to complete.
out, err = process.communicate()  # Capture what it outputted on STDOUT and STDERR
errcode = process.returncode  # Harvest its returncode, if needed.
print(out)
print('done running command')
```

Additionally, I wouldn't use `shell = True` unless it's really required. It forces subprocess to fire up a whole shell environment just to run a command. It's usually better to inject directly into the env parameter of Popen.

Comment: Thanks. This works but has one limitation - you can't see any output until after the command completes. I found an answer from another question that uses popen but also lets me see the output in real time. Here's what I ended up with this:

Comment: Ugh. ignore my previous comment. I'm lame - I could not figure out how to post code in a comment.

Comment: if `cmd` generates enough output then your code deadlocks. You should drain the pipe if you use `subprocess.PIPE`. Remove `process.wait()` before `process.communicate()`.