# Can't execute shell script from python subprocess: permission denied

Tags: python, shell

Tried googling but couldn't find something that relates to my particular problem. I'm trying to run a shell script from python but the shell script wouldn't run because of a permission denied error. The python code I'm running is:

```
process = subprocess.Popen('run.sh', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()
....
os.killpg(pro.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

The error I'm getting:

```
python RunScript.py "input"
/bin/sh: 1: run.sh: Permission denied
```

The contents of my shell script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
abspath=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd)
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$abspath/"lib/*":$abspath/"bin"
export CLASSPATH
java -classpath $CLASSPATH my.folder.path.Class $abspath/../data/data.txt $abspath/../data/data2.txt
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't use `PIPE` unless you read/write from/to the pipe. It blocks subprocess if it generates enough output. [To discard output, you could redirect it to `os.devnull`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11269575/4279)

Comment: you probably need [`preexec_fn=os.setsid` if you are going to use `os.killpg()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20184895/4279)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Check your run.sh mode, if no executable flag, set it with command

```
chmod +x run.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

its because you don't have permission to run that script. You will need to give executable permission for that script to run.

> chmod a+x run.sh