# "[Errno 13] Permission denied" When trying to update/change a document only on Ubuntu server

Tags: python, django, linux, ubuntu, virtualenv

When changing/updating infromation in the Admin backend of Django app, I'm met with a permission error.

A couple of things to note:
-It only happens when I try to upload a document, or change an entry with a document in it.
-Adding/editing database entries with no files attached to them is fine!
-On my local version, everything works fine.

The next logical step for me is to check file/folder permissions,
so I changed everything to on my testing server 'lrwxrwxrwx', including the uploads folder, the entirty of Python3.5 (I changed back after that did not solve it, I know it's pretty risky to leave it at all permissions).

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    https://admin/inhouse/document/1704/change/
Django Version: 1.11
Exception Type: PermissionError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 13] Permission denied
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py in _execute_child, line 1551
Python Executable:  /home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.5.2
Python Path:    
['/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/lib/python35.zip',
 '/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/lib/python3.5',
 '/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
 '/home/ubuntu/foodlegal/foodlegal-repo',
 '/home/ubuntu/foodlegal',
 '/home/ubuntu/.virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/extensions']
```

And this is the function that is causing this entire issue

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Document)
def convert_pdf_upload(sender, instance, **kwargs):

    if not instance.document_file:
        return

    current_path = settings.BASE_DIR+'/foodlegal/'+instance.document_file.url
    pdf_path = settings.BASE_DIR+'/foodlegal/uploads/documents/'+str(instance.id)+'.pdf'
    swf_path = settings.BASE_DIR+'/foodlegal/uploads/documents/'+str(instance.id)+'.swf'
    txt_path = settings.BASE_DIR+'/foodlegal/uploads/documents/'+str(instance.id)+'.txt'

    pdf2swf_path = settings.BASE_DIR+'/foodlegal/tools/pdf2swf'
    pdftotext_path = settings.BASE_DIR+'/foodlegal/tools/pdftotext'

    try:
        os.rename(current_path, pdf_path)
    except OSError:
        pass
    subprocess.call([pdf2swf_path, pdf_path, '-o', swf_path, '-f', '-T', '9', '-t', '-s',
                    'storeallcharacters'])

    subprocess.call([pdftotext_path, pdf_path])
    txt = codecs.open(txt_path, "r", encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')
    file_txt = txt.read()
    instance.file_text = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+', ' ', file_txt)

    if instance.content_type in [1, 2]:
        instance.file_text = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+', ' ', instance.document_content)

    post_save.disconnect(convert_pdf_upload, sender=Document)
    instance.save()
    post_save.connect(convert_pdf_upload, sender=Document)
```

Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

Tried changing permisions via chmod 777 to folders including Python3.5, entirety of InHouse Django App, and uploads folder, and was unsuccessful.

It could very well be a permission chmod fix type of thing, but what folder did I miss?

[Here is what the traceback calls look like](https://justpaste.it/1wrhq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the scripts within `/foodlegal/tools` executable in order to interact with them via `subprocess.call` like this. While in that directory:

```
chmod +x pdf2swf
chmod +x pdftotext
```

(Is there a `.sh` on those?)

Further reading: [Can't execute shell script from python subprocess: permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20291543/cant-execute-shell-script-from-python-subprocess-permission-denied)

Comment: You beautiful soul. That is exactly what was wrong, I can't believe I missed it.