# Pipe bash to a specific python flag

Tags: python, bash, pipe, argparse

I am writing a program in python to search my .bib-files for LaTeX with several flags. For that purpose I am using the `argparse` package for python.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=description_string, usage=usage_string, add_help=True)
parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", type=str, help=file_help_text)
parser.add_argument("-s", "--signifier", type=str, action='append',help=signifier_help_text)
parser.add_argument("-a", "--attribute", type=str, help=attribute_help_text)
parser.add_argument("-q", "--query", type=str, help=query_help_text)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Since I want to be able to use the program in the terminal, want to be able to pipe information from other processes to the script. Specifically, I want any string piped to the script to be used as the input to the -q / --query option of my script.

I have already read the following question and it did not solve my problem:
[Bash pipe to python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30043857/bash-pipe-to-python)

How can I control to which input-flag the piped strings go? Is there a package for it? It would really make my script more useful if I could pip into it.

Comment: If you want to pipe them I think you'll have to write your own parser ... you could, alternatively, use `./my_script.py --some param --query $( my_bash_script )`   ...

Comment: Well, this is a bit clunky, but it works, if I put " " around the argument. Thank you! I will see, if a parser is worth the effort.

Comment: `argparse` parses `sys.argv`.  Piped data is read from `sys.stdin`, as shown in the link.  Those are different sources.

Answer (score 0):

You can get `argparse` to take input from somewhere else than `sys.argv`. Perhaps first check if there's standard input. If not, prepare argument list `arglist` equal to `sys.argv` or its useful part. If yes, make it `sys.argv` with appended 1 line read from standard input.

```py
import sys

arglist = sys.argv[1:]
if not sys.stdin.isatty():
    query = sys.stdin.read(1)
    arglist.append(query) #or perhaps "--query "+query
```

Finally, parse it like usual, but with `arglist` as a parameter:

```py
args = parser.parse_args(arglist)
```