# Run a process in python, writing the process output to stdout?

Tags: python

I want to run a process from a python script, blocking while it runs, and writing the output of the process to stdout.

How would I do this?

I looked at the documentation for 'subprocess' but couldn't work it out.

*Editing this question to explain how it's different, as requested:*
See existing text above: **and writing the output of the process to stdout**

Comment: Printing to stdout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082850/real-time-subprocess-popen-via-stdout-and-pipe

Comment: Thanks - waiting until the command is done is one aspect of what I'm after. I could achieve that with `call`, I think (that's what I've found). One extra feature is that I also want the output to be streamed to my console.

Comment: why not just use   `subprocess.check_call([command])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `wait()` method for that.

For example:

```
# main_script.py

#some code

p1 = subprocess.Popen(['/path/to/process.sh'], shell=True) 
p1.wait()

#rest of code when process is done
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `object.communicate()[0]`

```
p=subprocess.Popen(["python","1st.py"],stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE)
print p.communicate()[0]

Communicate() will hold the last processed process output.
```