# read subprocess stdout line by line

Tags: python, subprocess

My python script uses subprocess to call a linux utility that is very noisy.  I want to store all of the output to a log file and show some of it to the user.  I thought the following would work, but the output doesn't show up in my application until the utility has produced a significant amount of output.

```
# fake_utility.py, just generates lots of output over time
import time
i = 0
    while True:
        print(hex(i)*512)
        i += 1
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

In the parent process:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'fake_utility.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in proc.stdout:
    # the real code does filtering here
    print("test:", line.rstrip())
```

The behavior I really want is for the filter script to print each line as it is received from the subprocess, like [`tee`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tee) does but within Python code.

What am I missing?  Is this even possible?

---

Comment: you could use `print line,` instead of `print line.rstrip()` (note: comma at the end).

Comment: related: [Python: read streaming input from `subprocess.communicate()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2715847/4279)

Comment: Update 2 states that it works with python 3.0+ but uses the old print statement, so it does not work with python 3.0+.

Comment: None of the answers listed here worked for me, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411780/python-run-a-daemon-sub-process-read-stdout/5413588#5413588 did!

Comment: interesting the code that only works in python3.0+ uses 2.7 syntax for print.

Comment: the update does not work. you're only printing line by line, not receiving them one by one.

Answer (score 241, accepted):

I think the problem is with the statement `for line in proc.stdout`, which reads the entire input before iterating over it. The solution is to use `readline()` instead:

```
#filters output
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['python','fake_utility.py'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
  line = proc.stdout.readline()
  if not line:
    break
  #the real code does filtering here
  print "test:", line.rstrip()
```

Of course you still have to deal with the subprocess' buffering.

Note: [according to the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.next) the solution with an iterator should be equivalent to using `readline()`, except for the read-ahead buffer, but (or exactly because of this) the proposed change did produce different results for me (Python 2.5 on Windows XP).

Comment: for `file.readline()` vs. `for line in file` see http://bugs.python.org/issue3907 (in short: it works on Python3; use `io.open()` on Python 2.6+)

Comment: The more pythonic test for an EOF, per the "Programming Recommendations" in PEP 8 (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), would be 'if not line:'.

Comment: there is no `open()` used in this script; where do you put `io.open()`? is there a workaround for 2.5?

Comment: @naxa: for pipes: `for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ''):`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: did you try this solution on Python3? I have code that previously ran on Python 2(.7) using the `iter(proc.stdout.readline, '')` approach, and now that I switched to Python 3.4 that code went pear-shaped, the loop does not return and RAM usage oscillates between ~0 and 3 GB.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke: yes. 1. you could use `for line in proc.stdout` on Python 3 (there is no the read-ahead bug) 2. `'' != b''` on Python 3 -- don't copy-paste the code blindly -- think what it does and how it works.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: sure, the `iter(f.readline, b'')` solution is rather obvious (and also works on Python 2, if anyone is interested). The point of my comment was not to blame your solution (sorry if it appeared like that, I read that now, too!), but to describe the extent of the symptoms, which are quite severe in this case (most of the Py2/3 issues result in exceptions, whereas here a well-behaved loop changed to be endless, and garbage collection struggles fighting the flood of newly created objects, yielding memory usage oscillations with long period and large amplitude).

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke: whether to use `''` or `b''` depends on `universal_newlines` parameter that enables text mode. It is not obvious. There are parameters that are different on Python 2 and 3. You should be careful if you write single source Python 2/3 compatible code that uses `subprocess` module.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I agree that there is a lot to consider when using `subprocess`, but usage of `b''` fits *most* application scenarios, because the well-chosen default in both, Python 2 and 3 is to treat `subprocess.PIPE` as a byte stream, and to not implicitly perform de/encoding operations. I'd say `b''` is recommendable even on Python 2, because it is semantically better (explicit). Indeed, `b''` would be wrong with `universal_newlines=True` on Python 3 (which renders `stdout/err` attributes to be `TextIOWrapper` objects). On Python 2, `b''` works independent of `universal_newlines`.

Comment: How can you see if `proc` has terminated before trying to read another line from its stdout?

Comment: Does this care how frequently or infrequently the called process sends output? Could it run indefinitely for months only printing a line every 30 seconds? I don't understand how `readline()` can determine when the program output is actually finished...

Comment: I recommmend to add `sys.stdout.flush()` before breaking, otherwise things mix up.

Comment: @JasonMock `if not line:` will also break on the first empty line (which is not necessarily at the end of the stream). `if line is not None:` should work properly.

Answer (score 101):

Bit late to the party, but was surprised not to see what I think is the simplest solution here:

```
import io
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(["prog", "arg"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in io.TextIOWrapper(proc.stdout, encoding="utf-8"):  # or another encoding
    # do something with line
```

(This requires Python 3.)

Comment: I'd like to use this answer but I am getting: `AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'readable'`  py2.7

Comment: Works with python 3

Comment: Clearly this code is not valid for multiple reasons py3/py3 compatibility and real risk of getting ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: @sorin neither of those things make it "not valid". If you're writing a library that still needs to support Python 2, then don't use this code. But many people have the luxury of being able to use software released more recently than a decade ago. If you try to read on a closed file you'll get that exception regardless of whether you use `TextIOWrapper` or not. You can simply handle the exception.

Comment: you are maybe late to the party but you answer is up to date with current version of Python, ty

Comment: This logic works fine but i am getting extra '\n' at every line. Is there a way to suppress that?

Comment: @Ammad `\n` is the newline character. it's conventional in Python for the newline to not be removed when splitting by lines - you'll see the same behaviour if you iterate over a file's lines or use a `readlines()` method. You can get the line without it with just `line[:-1]` (TextIOWrapper operates in "universal newlines" mode by default, so even if you're on Windows and the line ends with `\r\n`, you'll only have `\n` at the end, so `-1` works). You can also use `line.rstrip()` if you don't mind any other whitespace-like characters at the end of the line also being removed.

Comment: I got `AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'readable'` on python 3.7, but it was because  I was using `subprocess.run` instead of `subprocess.Popen`.

Comment: This was a good answer, but the `io.TextIOWrapper` isn't really needed anymore -  for modern Python versions, just create the `Popen` in text mode.

Answer (score 29):

Indeed, if you sorted out the iterator then buffering could now be your problem. You could tell the python in the sub-process not to buffer its output.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['python','fake_utility.py'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

becomes

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['python','-u', 'fake_utility.py'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I have needed this when calling python from within python.

Answer (score 22):

**A function that allows iterating over both `stdout` and `stderr` concurrently, in realtime, line by line**

In case you need to get the output stream for both `stdout` and `stderr` at the same time, you can use the following function.

The function uses Queues to merge both Popen pipes into a single iterator.

Here we create the function `read_popen_pipes()`:

```py
from queue import Queue, Empty
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def enqueue_output(file, queue):
    for line in iter(file.readline, ''):
        queue.put(line)
    file.close()


def read_popen_pipes(p):

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(2) as pool:
        q_stdout, q_stderr = Queue(), Queue()

        pool.submit(enqueue_output, p.stdout, q_stdout)
        pool.submit(enqueue_output, p.stderr, q_stderr)

        while True:

            if p.poll() is not None and q_stdout.empty() and q_stderr.empty():
                break

            out_line = err_line = ''

            try:
                out_line = q_stdout.get_nowait()
            except Empty:
                pass
            try:
                err_line = q_stderr.get_nowait()
            except Empty:
                pass

            yield (out_line, err_line)
```

`read_popen_pipes()` in use:

```py
import subprocess as sp


with sp.Popen(my_cmd, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, text=True) as p:

    for out_line, err_line in read_popen_pipes(p):

        # Do stuff with each line, e.g.:
        print(out_line, end='')
        print(err_line, end='')

    return p.poll() # return status-code
```

Answer (score 18):

You want to pass these extra parameters to `subprocess.Popen`:

```
bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True
```

Then you can iterate as in your example.  (Tested with Python 3.5)

Comment: @nicoulaj It should work if using the subprocess32 package.

Answer (score 8):

The `subprocess` module has come a long way since 2010, and most of the answers here are quite outdated.

Here is a simple way working for modern Python versions:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

with Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, text=True) as proc:
    for line in proc.stdout:
        print(line)
rc = proc.returncode
```

About using [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) as a context-manager (supported since Python 3.2): on exit of the `with` block, standard file descriptors are closed, and the process is waited / returncode attribute set. See [`subprocess.py:Popen.__exit__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.2/Lib/subprocess.py#L1092-L1118) in CPython sources.

Answer (score 6):

You can also read lines w/o loop. Works in python3.6.

```
import os
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
list_of_byte_strings = process.stdout.readlines()
```

Comment: Or to convert into strings: `list_of_strings = [x.decode('utf-8').rstrip('\n') for x in iter(process.stdout.readlines())]`

Comment: @ndtreviv, you can pass text=True to Popen or use its "encoding" kwarg if you want the output as strings, no need to convert it yourself

Answer (score 5):

Pythont 3.5 added the methods `run()` and `call()` to the `subprocess` module, both returning a `CompletedProcess` object. With this you are fine using `proc.stdout.splitlines()`:

```
proc = subprocess.run( comman, shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True, check=True )
for line in proc.stdout.splitlines():
   print "stdout:", line
```

See also [How to Execute Shell Commands in Python Using the Subprocess Run Method](https://linuxhint.com/execute_shell_python_subprocess_run_method/)

Comment: This solution is short and effective. One problem, compared to the original question: it does not print each line "as it is received," which I think means printing the messages in realtime just as if running the process directly in the command line. Instead it only prints the output _after_ the process finishes running.

Comment: Thanks @sfuqua for mentioning that. I use pipelines extensively and rely on streaming data and would have wrongly chosen this for its brevity.

Comment: This does not answer the question. It buffers entire output of subprocess into memory.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this with python3 and it worked, [source](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2017/interacting-with-a-long-running-child-process-in-python/)

When you use `popen` to spawn the new thread, you tell the operating system to `PIPE` the `stdout` of the child processes so the parent process can read it and here, `stderr` is copied to the `stderr` of the parent process.

in `output_reader` we read each line of `stdout` of the child process by wrapping it in an `iter`ator that populates line by line output from the child process whenever a new line is ready.

```
def output_reader(proc):
    for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, b''):
        print('got line: {0}'.format(line.decode('utf-8')), end='')


def main():
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'fake_utility.py'],
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

    t = threading.Thread(target=output_reader, args=(proc,))
    t.start()

    try:
        time.sleep(0.2)
        import time
        i = 0
    
        while True:
        print (hex(i)*512)
        i += 1
        time.sleep(0.5)
    finally:
        proc.terminate()
        try:
            proc.wait(timeout=0.2)
            print('== subprocess exited with rc =', proc.returncode)
        except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
            print('subprocess did not terminate in time')
    t.join()
```

Comment: That's great, but it seems to use the normal `Popen`. Instead of just showing a code snippit, you should really describe how it is set apart and what it does. There is a lot in there that surprises the heck out of the reader, and we're supposed to keep to the principle of least surprise.

Comment: Thank you @MaartenBodewes, I added more details to the answer, please let me know if you have more comments

Comment: Much better, upvoted. I'll remove my comment, you can do the same :)

Answer (score 1):

I came here with the same problem, and found that none of the provided answers really worked for me. The closest was adding the `sys.std.flush()` to the child process, which works but means modifying that process, which I didn't want to do.

Setting the `bufsize=1` in the Popen() didn't seem to have any effect for my use case. I guess the problem is that the child process is buffering, regardless of how I call the Popen().

However, I found this question with similar problem ([How can I flush the output of the print function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-can-i-flush-the-output-of-the-print-function)) and one of the answers is to set the environment variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` when calling Popen. This works how I want it to, i.e. real-time line-by-line reading of the output of the child process.

Answer (score 0):

The following modification of Rômulo's answer works for me on Python 2 and 3 (2.7.12 and 3.6.1):

```py
import os
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
  line = process.stdout.readline()
  if line != '':
    os.write(1, line)
  else:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem with the arg list of Popen to update servers, the following code resolves this a bit.

```
import getpass
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

username = 'user1'
ip = '127.0.0.1'

print ('What is the password?')
password = getpass.getpass()
cmd1 = f"""sshpass -p {password} ssh {username}@{ip}"""
cmd2 = f"""echo {password} | sudo -S apt update"""
cmd3 = " && "
cmd4 = f"""echo {password} | sudo -S apt upgrade -y"""
cmd5 = " && "
cmd6 = "exit"
commands = [cmd1, cmd2, cmd3, cmd4, cmd5, cmd6]

command = " ".join(commands)

cmd = command.split()

with Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as p:
    for line in p.stdout:
        print(line, end='')
```

And to run the update on a local computer, the following code example does this.

```
import getpass
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

print ('What is the password?')
password = getpass.getpass()

cmd1_local = f"""apt update"""
cmd2_local = f"""apt upgrade -y"""
commands = [cmd1_local, cmd2_local]

with Popen(['echo', password], stdout=PIPE) as auth:
    for cmd in commands:
        cmd = cmd.split()
        with Popen(['sudo','-S'] + cmd, stdin=auth.stdout, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as p:
            for line in p.stdout:
                print(line, end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

An improved version of https://stackoverflow.com/a/57093927/2580077 and suitable to python 3.10

A function to iterate over both stdout and stderr of the process in parallel.

Improvements:

- Unified queue to maintain the order of entries in stdout and stderr.
- Yield all available lines in stdout and stderr - this is useful when the calling process is slower.
- Use blocking in the loop to prevent the process from utilizing 100% of the CPU.

```py
import time
from queue import Queue, Empty
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def enqueue_output(file, queue, level):
    for line in file:
        queue.put((level, line))
    file.close()


def read_popen_pipes(p, blocking_delay=0.5):

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(2) as pool:
        q = Queue()

        pool.submit(enqueue_output, p.stdout, q, 'stdout')
        pool.submit(enqueue_output, p.stderr, q, 'stderr')

        while True:
            if p.poll() is not None and q.empty():
                break

            lines = []
            while not q.empty():
                lines.append(q.get_nowait())

            if lines:
                yield lines

            # otherwise, loop will run as fast as possible and utilizes 100% of the CPU
            time.sleep(blocking_delay)
```

Usage:

```py
with subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as p:
    for lines in read_popen_pipes(p):
        # lines - all the log entries since the last loop run.
        print('ext cmd', lines)
        # process lines
```

Answer (score 0):

On Linux (and presumably OSX), sometimes the parent process doesn't see the output immediately because the child process is buffering its output (see [this article](https://pnote.eu/notes/command-line-output-buffering/) for a more detailed explanation).

If the child process is a Python program, you can disable this by setting the environment variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` to `1` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77133123/92010).

If the child process is not a Python program, you can sometimes trick it into running in line-buffered mode by creating a pseudo-terminal like so:

```py
import os
import pty
import subprocess

# Open a pseudo-terminal
master_fd, slave_fd = pty.openpty()

# Open the child process on the slave end of the PTY
with subprocess.Popen(
        ['python', 'fake_utility.py'],
        stdout=slave_fd,
        stdin=slave_fd,
        stderr=slave_fd) as proc:

    # Close our copy of the slave FD (without this we won't notice
    # when the child process closes theirs)
    os.close(slave_fd)

    # Convert the master FD into a file-like object
    with open(master_fd, 'r') as stdout:
        try:
            for line in stdout:
                # Do the actual filtering here
                print("test:", line.rstrip())
        except OSError:
            # This happens when the child process closes its STDOUT,
            # usually when it exits
            pass
```

If the child process needs to read from STDIN, you can get away without the `stdin=slave_fd` argument to `subprocess.Popen()`, as the child process should be checking the status of STDOUT (not STDIN) when it decides whether or not to use line-buffering.

Finally, some programs may actually directly open and write to their controlling terminal instead of writing to STDOUT. If you need to catch this case, you can use the `setsid` utility by replacing `['python', 'fake_utility.py'] with ['setsid', 'python', 'fake_utility.py']` in the call to `subprocess.Popen()`.