# web.py + subprocess = hang

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, freeze, web.py

Here's my main file:

```
import subprocess, time

pipe = subprocess.PIPE
popen = subprocess.Popen('pythonw -uB test_web_app.py', stdout=pipe)
time.sleep(3)
```

And here's test_web_app.py:

```
import web

class Handler:
  def GET(self):  pass
app = web.application(['/', 'Handler'], globals())
app.run()
```

When I run the main file, the program executes, but a zombie process is left hanging and I have to kill it manually.  Why is this?  How can I get the Popen to die when the program ends?  The Popen only hangs if I pipe stdout and sleep for a bit before the program ends.

**Edit -- here's the final, working version of the main file:**

```
import subprocess, time, atexit

pipe = subprocess.PIPE
popen = subprocess.Popen('pythonw -uB test_web_app.py', stdout=pipe)

def kill_app():
  popen.kill()
  popen.wait()
atexit.register(kill_app)

time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not [wait](http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411/www/NOTES/process/fork/wait.html)ed for the process. Once it's done, you have to call `popen.wait`.

You can check if the process is terminated using the `poll` method of the `popen` object to see if it has completed.

If you don't need the stdout of the web server process, you can simply ignore the stdout option.

---

You can use the [atexit](http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html) module to implement a hook that gets called when your main file exits. This should use the `kill` method of the `Popen` object and then `wait` on it to make sure that it's terminated.

Comment: The subprocess is never going to be done...  it keeps serving forever.  I want the subprocess to die when the parent process ends (when I close the console).  And I need the stdout.

Answer (score 1):

If your main script doesn't need to be doing anything else while the subprocess executes I'd do:

```
import subprocess, time

pipe = subprocess.PIPE
popen = subprocess.Popen('pythonw -uB test_web_app.py', stdout=pipe, stderr=pipe)
out, err = popen.communicate()
```

(I think if you specifically pipe stdout back to your program, you need to read it at some point to avoid creating zombie processes - communicate will read it in a reasonably safe way).

Or if you don't care about parsing stdout / stderr, don't bother piping them:

```
popen = subprocess.Popen('pythonw -uB test_web_app.py')
popen.communicate()
```

Comment: The main script does need to be doing stuff.  The real version of the main script captures output from the subprocess, applies some fancy formatting, and displays the output live -- non-blocking.

Comment: Oh, in that case it's a bit trickier, and not something I've done sorry - though this question might point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804543/read-subprocess-stdout-line-by-line