# Widget to Display subprocess stdout?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a python based tkinter script which executes some commands using subprocess module.
I need to display the standard output on the GUI itself.
Since I am new to tk (One week Bold :) ), I need your advice How should i proceed. 
I have two queries:

1. Which widget should I learn to display the stdout.
2. How to link the stdout of subprocess to the widget you have mentioned.

Comment: Are the subprocesses quick to run or long-running?

Comment: long running, the process may take 5-10 minutes to execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use the `Tkinter.Text` widget, described [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm).

The description is quite long, but what you need to understand is mainly that this widget can be used as a buffer, as text should be inserted inside.

So, for each new line in the `subprocess` output, you will have to insert text where you want it. Example:

```
t = Tkinter.Text(root)
while some_condition:
    s = p.readline()          # get subprocess output
    t.insert(END, s)
```

**EDIT** Have [a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804543/read-subprocess-stdout-line-by-line) for getting subprocess output line by line.

You may also want to have a look to `Tkinter.Scrollbar` and `Text.see()` to tune the display.

Comment: While that's the _outline_ of what's needed, you want to keep the GUI live during the processing. That makes things quite a lot more complex (though not as much as if you want to interact with the subprocess; there are many subtleties).

Comment: That's right, keeping activity is a bit different, as GUI has to be refreshed. But this is more application-dependent: is the GUI the root of the program, or just a display? This will have two different answers, using `root.after()` or access to `t` properties.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your replies. I will look in to the links and will get back to you.
Actually I have a huge csh script which is quite complex to use. With GUI, I am trying to isolate user from the complexity. Hence it is essential to give user real time of csh script execution.

Comment: I had yesterday tried similar implementation as you suggested, the only issue was that I was getting stdout in text box only once the execution was finished in console.

Comment: Is the answer given in the question linked in my first edit working? Second question, could you please publish the code you have so far? There's a little trick to make with GUI, since they are not procedural but event-driven (I hope I have the correct terms).