# Display realtime output of a subprocess in a tkinter widget

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, subprocess

My question is almost the same as this one:
[Widget to Display subprocess stdout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133487/widget-to-display-subprocess-stdout)
but a step further.

I have the following code (python2.7):

```
def btnGoClick(p1):
    params = w.line.get()
    if len(params) == 0:
        return

    # create child window
    win = tk.Toplevel()
    win.title('Bash')
    win.resizable(0, 0)
    # create a frame to be able to attach the scrollbar
    frame = ttk.Frame(win)
    # the Text widget - the size of the widget define the size of the window
    t = tk.Text(frame, width=80, bg="black", fg="green")
    t.pack(side="left", fill="both")
    s = ttk.Scrollbar(frame)
    s.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    # link the text and scrollbar widgets
    s.config(command=t.yview)
    t.config(yscrollcommand=s.set)
    frame.pack()

    process = subprocess.Popen(["<bashscript>", params], shell=False,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

    while True:
        out = process.stdout.readline()
        if out == '' and process.poll() is not None:
            break
        print out
        t.insert(tk.END, out)
```

The output from the "longrunning" bash script is captured in realtime (appear in the console) but the Tkinter window appear only after the end of the subprocess !!

How can I have the window appearing before the subprocess start and update its content in realtime ?

Comment: to avoid blocking the GUI, you could put `readline()` into separate thread, [example](https://gist.github.com/zed/42324397516310c86288)

Comment: if you are on a POSIXy system then you could also [use `createfilehandler()` to get output from the subprocess in "real-time"](https://gist.github.com/zed/9294978) instead of the explicit threads.

Comment: related: [Redirect command line results to a tkinter GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/q/665566/4279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.
After the window construction, you must add :

```
frame.pack()
# force drawing of the window
win.update_idletasks()
```

And then after every line insertion in the widget, you must also force a refresh with the same method only on the widget.

```
# insert the line in the Text widget
t.insert(tk.END, out)
# force widget to display the end of the text (follow the input)
t.see(tk.END)
# force refresh of the widget to be sure that thing are displayed
t.update_idletasks()
```

Comment: as suspected, I tried and this example is not really work. If as command you use something like "ls -Rf /" you will see that the while loop will make the window txt output flowing pretty well. However both windows (main and secondary) will block big time.

Comment: yes, it's correct. During the output, everything is blocked and it's just an output. you can't interact with it. But this is what I need.

Comment: Mate, it can't possibly be that you want this behaviour. The usability of the GUI is compromised by this behaviour. Resize, close button, minimize button is all frozen.

Comment: well, this is not really a big deal, as the purpose of the interface is to launch this subprocess which doesn't take, anyway, not so much time. I will try to implement the solution proposed by J.F. Sebastian, to see if thing can be improved

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting solution. Would that be possible to have the whole working code?

I am asking because I was wonder how the `while True` does not block the usability of the whole GUI... does it not?

As suspected, I tried and this example is not really work. If you use something like "`ls -Rf /`" as command, you will see that the while loop will make the txt output flowing pretty well. However both windows (main and secondary) will block big time.

I suspect you need to send the print txt part in a separated thread or process. Or, if you use pygtk you can use stuff like

```
gobject.io_add_watch(self.ep1.stdout,       # file descriptor
                     gobject.IO_IN,         # condition
                     self.write_to_buffer ) # callback
```

which was actually invented for this.

Comment: here's two examples: [one uses `io_add_watch()`, another -- threads](https://gist.github.com/zed/8a255e81eb87431c0e63)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone else is looking for it...

```
log_box_1 = tk.Text(root, borderwidth=3, relief="sunken")

with subprocess.Popen("ls -la", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as p:
            for line in p.stdout:
                log_box_1.insert(tk.END, line)
```

From [here](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=5gxTDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA369&lpg=PA369&dq=how%20to%20set%20popen%20stdout%20to%20a%20tkinter%20text&source=bl&ots=lO0NPnalhq&sig=ACfU3U319-Q8DV6M4GwPaFb0-HyzPjQdHg&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjv06nvzuniAhVpIrkGHZNXC_gQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=how%20to%20set%20popen%20stdout%20to%20a%20tkinter%20text&f=false)