# Issues intercepting subprocess output in real time

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, subprocess, stdout

I've spent about 6 hours on stack overflow, rewriting my python code and trying to get this to work. It just doesn't tho. No matter what I do.

**The goal:**
Getting the output of a subprocess to appear in real time in a tkinter text box.

**The issue:**
I can't figure out how to make the Popen work in real time. It seems to hang until the process is complete. (Run on its own, the process works completely as expected, so it's just this thing that has the error)

**Relevant code:**

```
import os
import tkinter
import tkinter.ttk as tk
import subprocess

class Application (tk.Frame):
    process = 0
    def __init__ (self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets (self):
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.quit)
        self.quitButton.grid()
        self.console = tkinter.Text(self)
        self.console.config(state=tkinter.DISABLED)
        self.console.grid()

    def startProcess (self):
        dir = "C:/folder/"
        self.process = subprocess.Popen([ "python", "-u", dir + "start.py" ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=dir)
        self.updateLines()

    def updateLines (self):
        self.console.config(state=tkinter.NORMAL)
        while True:
            line = self.process.stdout.readline().decode().rstrip()
            if line == '' and self.process.poll() != None:
                break
            else: 
                self.console.insert(tkinter.END, line + "\n")
        self.console.config(state=tkinter.DISABLED)
        self.after(1, self.updateLines)

app = Application()
app.startProcess()
app.mainloop()
```

Also, feel free to destroy my code if it's written poorly. This is my first python project, I don't expect to be any good at the language yet.

Comment: related: [Display realtime output of a subprocess in a tkinter widget](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15362372/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `process.stdout.readline()` will block until a full line is available. This means the condition `line == ''` will never be met until the process exits. You have two options around this.

First you can set stdout to non-blocking and manage a buffer yourself. It would look something like this. EDIT: As Terry Jan Reedy pointed out this is a Unix only solution. The second alternative should be preferred.

```
import fcntl
...

    def startProcess(self):
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(['./subtest.sh'],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            bufsize=0) # prevent any unnecessary buffering

        # set stdout to non-blocking
        fd = self.process.stdout.fileno()
        fl = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
        fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, fl | os.O_NONBLOCK)

        # schedule updatelines
        self.after(100, self.updateLines)

    def updateLines(self):
        # read stdout as much as we can
        line = ''
        while True:
            buff = self.process.stdout.read(1024)
            if buff:
                buff += line.decode()
            else:
                break

        self.console.config(state=tkinter.NORMAL)
        self.console.insert(tkinter.END, line)
        self.console.config(state=tkinter.DISABLED)

        # schedule callback
        if self.process.poll() is None:
            self.after(100, self.updateLines)
```

The second alternative is to have a separate thread read the lines into a queue. Then have updatelines pop from the queue. It would look something like this

```
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue, Empty

def readlines(process, queue):
    while process.poll() is None:
        queue.put(process.stdout.readline())
...

    def startProcess(self):
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(['./subtest.sh'],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

        self.queue = Queue()
        self.thread = Thread(target=readlines, args=(self.process, self.queue))
        self.thread.start()

        self.after(100, self.updateLines)

    def updateLines(self):
        try:
            line = self.queue.get(False) # False for non-blocking, raises Empty if empty
            self.console.config(state=tkinter.NORMAL)
            self.console.insert(tkinter.END, line)
            self.console.config(state=tkinter.DISABLED)
        except Empty:
            pass

        if self.process.poll() is None:
            self.after(100, self.updateLines)
```

The threading route is probably safer. I'm not positive that setting stdout to non-blocking will work on all platforms.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. I used the threading route, haven't tested the other one. Is there any benefit to using 100 milliseconds in the self.after, rather than a smaller number?

Comment: Also, since you seem to be pretty learned with python, would you happen to know if I should use process.communicate to send a new command to the subprocess?

Comment: @Aarilight First, I totally forgot to mention that if your subprocess is a python script, its probably a better idea to turn your script into a proper module. Then you can import it for finer control and avoid all the subprocess stuff. About your second question, `communicate` will block until the subprocess exits which is not what you want. In this case you need to use `stdin.write()`, but beware that this can cause blocking or deadlocking. I'll try to find a link for you about when this can happen.

Comment: I asked a new question about it because I tried both of them and neither seemed to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27334037/how-to-send-a-new-command-to-a-subprocess

Comment: @Aarilight ok, I'll see if I have any insight on that when I get back tonight. In the mean time [this](http://thraxil.org/users/anders/posts/2008/03/13/Subprocess-Hanging-PIPE-is-your-enemy/) is the best link I found about the deadlock issue. The main thing is be sure that your std* buffers are being flushed so they dont fill up and block.

Comment: fcntl is unix-only.  I do not know if it works on OSX or if there is another method of making files (pipes) non-blocking on windows.