# Tkinter threading and return to text widget

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter

I've read some post on stack overflow,[Issues intercepting subprocess output in real time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327886/issues-intercepting-subprocess-output-in-real-time), [Redirect command line results to a tkinter GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665566/redirect-command-line-results-to-a-tkinter-gui), i know i have to use threading and queue in tkinter, but I am still can't do the same thing because I am a beginner in program,please help.

**The goal**: When press a button, getting the 'top' command output and realtime display in tkinter text widget

**The issue**: I've tried to follow the code, but still cannot get the output, but I have not idea how to make it work.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('realtime')
window.geometry('800x400')








text = tk.Text(window)
text.pack()
button = tk.Button(window, text= 'Press')
button.pack()


window.mainloop()
```

This is only the gui outlook, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`top` refreshes itself now and then and I'm guessing that's the behavior you want to capture with threading and whatnot. However in this case it would be much easier to ask `top` to only run once, and have tkinter do the timing and refreshing:

```
import tkinter as tk
from sh import top

def update_text():
    text.delete(0.0, tk.END)
    text.insert(0.0, top('-b', n=1))
    window.after(1000, update_text) # call this function again in 1 second

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('realtime')
window.geometry('800x400')

text = tk.Text(window)
text.pack()
button = tk.Button(window, text= 'Press', command=update_text)
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

You may need to install [`sh`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sh) to run top like I did, or use `subprocess.check_output` if you want.

```
text.insert(0.0, subprocess.check_output(['top', '-b', '-n 1']))
```

Comment: Can you help my other question please?[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43388789/use-variable-in-different-class)