# print output of subprocess call into a label tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess

I am trying to create a GUI in tkinter. The Gui is basically for [Mcp23017](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21952b.pdf). I am trying to configure the input and output pins so that the user could change them according to their choice.. There is also an option to make the inputs/outputs high or low..

Now I am trying to read a pin using 'i2cget'(using a seperate function).. I need to display the output of this subprocess call into a label on the gui..

This is what my code looks like:

```
def read_p22():
   output = subprocess.call(['i2cget -y 0x20 0x12 0xFD'],shell=True)
   x=print (output)
   Label(tableframe,textvariable=x).grid(row=2,column=20)
   root.after(5000, read_p22)
```

When this function excutes(by pressing a button), however it prints a value '1' on the python shell alternatly when I press the button... I dont know how to redirect the output to the label.. Could somebody suggest something?

Update:: On executing the suggested commands:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['i2cget -y 0x20 0x12 0xFD'], stdout=PIPE,      stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
output, code = process.communicate()
```

I printed the 'output' and 'process' and they gave me the follwing respectivley:

```
b'' <subprocess.Popen object at 0x00000000035CB2B0>
```

Since nothing is connected to the pin I expect it to return a value of '0'.. I don't know what is the b'' it is giving me ...

Any advice is really appreciated..

Kind Regards,
Namita.

Comment: the b'' you are getting returned is pythons was of displaying an empty byte string, as it does not have a specific encoding with it

Comment: @James Kent: Thank you for clarifying that for me..:) But shouldn't it give me a '0' instead? Or will it give a 0 only when I actually connect something? And also this (b'') still appears on the shell not in the GUI. Is there a way I could put it on the GUI?

Comment: if you don't know what `b''` is then you should learn some Python first before trying to combine `tkinter` and `subprocess`. If you already know some other programming language then [read the official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) otherwise [start with Python for Non-Programmers](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers)

Answer (score 1):

What you have is the return code, not the output.

From [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) docs:

> Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then **return the returncode attribute**.

Instead, use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) to open a process, [`subprocess.PIPE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.PIPE) to pipe the output to you, and [`Popen.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) get the output:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['i2cget -y 0x20 0x12 0xFD'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
output, code = process.communicate()
# do stuff with output...
```

Comment: Thank You for that quick response.. :) I tried what you said.. It gives me a error saying     output, code = process.communicate()
NameError: name 'process' is not defined . What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @NamitaRaju if it's not working don't accept the answer. I fixed it by renaming the `Popen` object to `process`.

Comment: I am sorry, but I did not understand what you meant by renaming the Popen object..

Comment: @NamitaRaju I've fixed it in the answer itself. The `Popen` object was named `output` (first line), and referred to by `process` (second line).

Comment: What does `i2cget -y 0x20 0x12 0xFD` return? Update your question to include the output of the command and what you expect to appear. Try and print `output` to see what it contains.

Comment: I updated my question.. Could you please be kind enough to have a look

Comment: the 2nd variable is not `code`; it is `stderr_output`. Don't use a list with `shell=True`; just pass a string (the shell command) as is. Anyway `shell=True` is probably unnecessary here.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian well, he used it to use `/bin/sh`. Maybe it is necessary.

Comment: OP doesn't know what `b''` is in Python. It suggests that `shell=True` is most likely unnecessary here.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things wrong in your code. You should split your problem into tiny tiny subtasks and complete each task independently.

### 1. Get output from a subprocess as a string variable in Python

[`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) returns an integer (exit status), not string (the output) -- start Python REPL and try to run any command via `subprocess` and see for yourself: it should help you to understand what is happening in addition to reading the linked documentation.

You could use `subprocess.check_output()`, to get the output if you don't mind blocking your GUI thread -- nothing will respond until the subprocess returns.

Otherwise (if `i2cget` does not return in an instant, always), you could [do it asynchroniously using threads or `.createfilehandler()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362372/display-realtime-output-of-a-subprocess-in-a-tkinter-widget#comment24334740_15362372).

### 2. Learn why `x = print(output)` is useless in Python

It is SyntaxError in Python 2 by default. Otherwise `print()` function *always* returns `None` i.e., you could have written `x = None` (except that `output` is printed to stdout as a side-effect).

### 3. Update text in a Label

- create a label only once instead of creating a new label every 5 seconds
- [pass `StringVar()` as a `textvariable` parameter](https://gist.github.com/zed/9294978#file-tkinter-read-async-subprocess-output-py-L39)
- [use `.set(new_text)` to update the text](https://gist.github.com/zed/9294978#file-tkinter-read-async-subprocess-output-py-L54)

Comment: @JFSebastian : Thank you for all the tips.. I am a beginner in python and thus the 'not so elegant' code.. I will try and use the suggestions you gave me.. _However regarding the 'subprocess.check_output', whenevr I try to use it and run it in my python 3 in win7 system it gives me the error saying    `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified `.. I don't really understand why.. Could you suggest something?

Comment: @NamitaRaju: make sure you can run the command that you pass to `check_output()` from the command-line (if you don't know what "the command-line" is -- [learn it first](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/appendixa.html)). If it works from the command line but fails with `check_output()` then create a [minimal but complete code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [post it as a separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @J.Fsebastian: Sorry I forgot to mention that I tried to run it from the command line too. But it gives me the same error.

Comment: @NamitaRaju: I meant, run the child process manually (without Python) -- so that you would know how the correct command should look like.