# Failed with running subprocess from Python launcher without terminal window on Mac

Tags: python, macos, subprocess, automator

My ultimate goal is to run a Python script (the code need to call some **subprocess**) without terminal.

I tried with **python launcher** on Mac.  The code works **correctly** when the **"Run in a Terminal window"** is checked.

(Notice that the `shell=False` is default here.)  However, it won't run the subprocess correctly when I uncheck that option.

I also tried to run in with Mac OS automator (**Run Shell Script**) — negative too.

Here is a small sample code.

```
import subprocess

with open("record","w") as f:
    subprocess.call(["which","ipython"], stdout = f)  # this line fails
    subprocess.call(["open","."])  # this line always works
```

If I run from terminal, it creates a record file, which shows the ipython path.  However when I run it from automator or python launcher without terminal window, it creates an empty file.

Comment: you could try to redirect all standard streams: stdin, stdout, stderr (use [`subprocess.DEVNULL` or its analog](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11270665/4279))

Comment: Thank you Sebastian.  However I still need to parse stdout in my case.

Comment: if you need stdout as  a string; use `output = check_output(cmd, stdin=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL)`

Comment: Thank you again!  Unfortunately I need to keep the process alive and monitor the stdout.  I used non-blocking stream in my situation (based on this [link](http://eyalarubas.com/python-subproc-nonblock.html) ).  The full scope of my project is to create a GUI for ipython notebook.  The project is [here](https://github.com/jiayiliu/inlauncher/blob/master/gui.py)

Comment: Here's a [portable way "to keep the process alive and monitor the stdout"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32682520/4279). If you need to support only Unix systems then you could use more straightforward [`createfilehandler()`-based solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362372/display-realtime-output-of-a-subprocess-in-a-tkinter-widget#comment43779465_15362372). A GUI for ipython notebook is a completely different question: look at how the current web-gui is done -- use the provided interface to communicate with ipython notebook kernels.