# python subprocess output to list or file

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I want to run the following bash command in Python 3:

```
ls -l
```

I know that I can do the following:

```
from subprocess import call
call(['ls', '-l'])
```

How do I save this output to a file, or put it into lists or sets?

```
[-rw-r--r--]  [1] [name]  [staff]   [426] [14 Jan 21:52] [HelloWorld.class]
[-rw-r--r--@] [1] [name]  [staff]   [107] [14 Jan 21:51] [HelloWorld.java]
...
etc.
```

I want to be able to access particular information directly, and then add it to the set, but I do not know how many items will be listed.

Any hints, snippets, or examples would really help.

Comment: If you want to access file/dir information you might want to check the built-in `os` library: [documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/os.html).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way to access to the information in `ls -l` output is to parse it. For example, `csv.DictReader` could be use to map each column to a field in a dictionary:

```
import subprocess
import csv

process = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-l'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

reader = csv.DictReader(stdout.decode('ascii').splitlines(),
                        delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True,
                        fieldnames=['permissions', 'links',
                                    'owner', 'group', 'size',
                                    'date', 'time', 'name'])

for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

The code above will print a dictionary for each line in `ls -l` output such as:

```
{'group': '<group_name>',
 'name': '<filename>',
 'links': '1',
 'date': '<modified_date>',
 'time': '<modified_time>',
 'owner': '<user_name>',
 'permissions': '-rw-rw-r--',
 'size': '<size>'}
```

Comment: I get: `  File "ip4.py", line 16
    print row
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @user969617 Yes, sorry, that was for python 2.x, not for python 3 as you asked. I've updated the code to work for python 3.

Comment: this looks promising!!! My next question (please bare with me, it's my second day of python) is how do I then access info from each dictionary. Do I need to give them unique names? Say I want to cross reference the date with a spreadsheet.

Comment: @user969617 There's no need to give a name to the dictionaries. You can store them in a list and access the list by index and the dictionary by key: `rows[0]['name']`

Comment: Thanks man your code works perfectly well for parsing

hadoop fs -ls

as well!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 29):

With >= python3.5 you can use [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run):

```
ls_lines = subprocess.run(['ls', '-l'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.splitlines()
```

With >= python2.7 or >= python3.0 you can use [subprocess.check_output](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
ls_lines = subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-l']).splitlines()
```

Prior to python2.7, you need to use the lower level api, which is a bit more involved.

```
ls_proc = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-l'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
ls_proc.wait()
# check return code
ls_lines = ls_proc.stdout.readlines()
```

Comment: subprocess.PIPE*

Answer (score 7):

If what you really want is to list a directory, rather use [os.listdir](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir)

```
import os
files = os.listdir('/path/to/dir')
for file in files:
    print(file)
```

Comment: i actually want to list the airport tables, but thought that I would use a simple example. The actual output is going to be `call(['/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport', '-s'])`

Answer (score 2):

Read about Popen. the set you asked for you get with

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['ls','-l'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
myset=set(proc.stdout)
```

or do something like

```
for x in proc.stdout : print x
```

and the same for stderr

you can examine the state of the process with

```
proc.poll()
```

or wait for it to terminate with

```
proc.wait()
```

also read

[read subprocess stdout line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804543/read-subprocess-stdout-line-by-line)

Answer (score 0):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
output = Popen(['ls', '-l'], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

You can then do whatever you want with the output. See [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) for detailed documentation

Comment: Thanks. I had tried this one as well, but was confused by the lack of formatting... Im used to doing things with bash & awk, where printing output and then using `awk '{print $n;}'` lets you get to columns and `awk NR=$variable` lets you select the lines.  Which section should I look at?

Comment: @Gary points out a nice way to do it for Python2.7+. Use that if you can :)

Answer (score 0):

People have already responded to it. Nevertheless, just in case somebody needs it

```
import subprocess
output_list=subprocess.check_output(['locate','*.nse']).decode('utf-8').split('\n')[:-1]
```