# Use input() with child processes in Python multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, stdin

I have several child processes running independent tasks, and from time to time one of them needs to ask for human input on the terminal.
The code uses a terminal input/output lock to make sure that it is safe to do so. However, as I discovered, stdin is disabled in child processes in multiprocessing.

I've looked around and I have found this way of doing it:

[Python user input in child process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835250/python-user-input-in-child-process)

There are a few other threads from around 2010-2012, suggesting essentially the same solution. However, the answer is almost 10 years old and Python has changed a bit since then. Is there any more "modern" way of doing it?