# How to use user input while multiprocessing

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-multiprocessing

How can I store variables from user inputs to use on functions? I'm using multiprocessing

I've seen this article but doesn't seem to apply to my situation

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47141057/unable-to-use-input-when-multiprocessing-in-python)

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
    import multiprocessing
    from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Value, Pool

    
    min = str(input('please input minimum seconds: '))
    max = str(input('please input maximum seconds: '))
    
    pstbinU1 = ''
    def userProc():
        global pstbinU1
        
        
        r = requests.get(pstbinU1)
        print(pstbinU1)
        sleep(10)
        content = r.text
        
        fp.writelines(content+'\n')
        fp.seek(0)
        links1 = fp.read()
        fp.close()
    
        
        ......codes here
   
        
        sleep(random.randint(min, max))
```

The pstbinU1 just returns a blank string and for the sleep min and max, I get EOF end of line error

Here is the main() function:

```
 def main():
    
        p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=userProc)
        p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=devProc)
    
    
        p1.start()
        p2.start()
    
        p1.join()
        print('Please wait for the "Finished processes" message before you close the app...')
        p2.join()
```

And here is the starter block:

```
   regex5 = (r'[a-zA-Z0-9\s_-]*')   
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        
        start = time.perf_counter()
    
    
        while True:
            text = str(input('Enter the pastebin raw URL(in http url form -> https://pastebin.com/raw/XXXXXXXX): '))
    
    ##        matches5 = re.match(regex5, text)
    ##        if matches5:
    
            if not text == '':
                pstbinU1 = text
    
    
                main()
    
            else:
                print('Please paste a proper Pastebin Raw Link...')
```

I don't know how to resolve this. Any help would be awesome... :)

Comment: You can read input in main process (instead of waiting on `join`) and pass read URL to subprocess using for example *multiprocessing.JoinableQueue*

Comment: Hi @PatrikPolakovic

Thank you for your reply. I've tried to apply the same issue above [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47141057/unable-to-use-input-when-multiprocessing-in-python), but it's an input of Y/N, so I'm not sure how to apply it in my case...

Comment: I tried to read [this link](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/57787/multiprocessing.JoinableQueue) but I can only understand very little. #10, 20 and 23 i think are very basic but I can't seem to understand how I will apply them to my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you can use *JoinableQueue*

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Value, Pool


def userProc(q, min, max):
    
    pstbinU1 = q.get()
    print(min, max, pstbinU1)

    try:
        r = requests.get(pstbinU1)
        
        sleep(10)
        content = r.text
        
        fp.writelines(content+'\n')
        fp.seek(0)
        links1 = fp.read()
        fp.close()

        
        sleep(random.randint(min, max))    
    except Exception:
        q.task_done()

def main(q, min, max):

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=userProc, args=(q, min, max))
    
    
    p1.start()
    p1.join()
    q.join()

regex5 = (r'[a-zA-Z0-9\s_-]*')   
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    min = str(input('please input minimum seconds: '))
    max = str(input('please input maximum seconds: '))

    q = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()

    while True:
        text = str(input('Enter the pastebin raw URL(in http url form -> https://pastebin.com/raw/XXXXXXXX): '))

        if not text == '':
            q.put(text)
            main(q, min, max)
            break
        else:
            print('Please paste a proper Pastebin Raw Link...')
            continue
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer & I've voted up but i'm just below 15 points so my vote is not public..


anyway, I've tried to add 2 more inputs but I got lost again

```def userProc(q, minW, maxW):
     pstbinU1 = q.get()
     minW = minW.get()
     maxW = maxW.get()

     print(f'here are args, {pstbinU1} : {min} : {max}')
     p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=userProc, args=(q, minW, maxW,))
I feel it's wrong... so on Main:
         if url or minW or maxW != '':
             q.put(text)
             minW.put(minW)
             maxW.put(maxW) ```
Thanks again

Comment: @digilevi2006 I've edited the solution. Check how *min* and *max* are passed to the subprocess. You don't have to use queue for that. Also if your program process only one URL and then exits, then you don't have to use queue at all. You can read everything in `main()`, then create subprocess and pass all values as arguments

Comment: Thank you for you help... I wanted to upvote your answer but can't do it :(
til next time

Comment: i have a similar problem and tried this - i need a user input in the main function when a specific thing happens, but with this, it prompts at the start of the script, not when the script reaches the `q.get()` - is that normal or am i doing it wrong? (cant open a new quesiton sadly)