# EOFError: EOF when reading a line (Python 3.11)

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, eof

Hello StackOverflow Community,
I'm struggling in resolving an `EOFError: EOF when reading a line` ERROR I've been hitting in my code for some reason and I've tried some possible ways to solve it I could find, ex. try/except function, but couldn't resolve it anyway, so that I'm asking you If you could help me on resolving this issue.

Here is the ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.181.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.181.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\grego\Documents\GitHub\notes-app\Noti.py", line 17, in checkPath
    takeQuickiPy()
  File "C:\Users\grego\Documents\GitHub\notes-app\Noti.py", line 23, in takeQuickiPy
    quickiPy = input(">    ")
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Here is the full code:

```
import os
import multiprocessing as mp
from os import listdir
import simple_chalk as chk

path = "./QuickiPies"
pathBoolean = os.path.exists(path)
quickiPy = "null"


def checkPath():
    if pathBoolean == False:
        os.mkdir(path)

    takeQuickiPy()


def takeQuickiPy():
    print(chk.greenBright.bold(
        "Welcome to NotiPy! By pressing Ctrl+Shift+S your QuickiPy will be saved to the QuickiPy directory. Open an existing QuickiPy with Ctrl+Shift+O."))
    quickiPy = input(">    ")


def checkShortcut():
    while True:
        if kd.is_pressed("ctrl+shift+o"):
            listDir()
            break
        elif kd.is_pressed("ctrl+shift+s"):
            saveQuickiPy()
            break


def listDir():
    print("Choose your QuickiPy:")
    for i in listdir(path):
        print(i)


def saveQuickiPy():
    file = open(path + "/" + "note.txt", "w")
    file.write(quickiPy)
    file.close()
    print(chk.greenBright.bold("QuickiPy saved!"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    process1 = mp.Process(target=checkPath)
    jobs.append(process1)
    process2 = mp.Process(target=checkShortcut)
    jobs.append(process2)
    process1.start()
    process2.start()
```

PS: The program is supposed to be a notepad terminal-like program in which you are prompted to write input, but when *Ctrl+Shift+S* is hit, the program will save the input into a file, and if *Ctrl+Shift+O* is hit, the program will list all the files available in the directory to open (this function isn't implemented for now).

**Thank you for any possible solutions.**

Comment: You need to pull your input into the main thread. You might want to check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62949599/how-to-use-user-input-while-multiprocessing
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47141057/unable-to-use-input-when-multiprocessing-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using **multiprocessing**, you should use **threading** as multiprocessing does not wait until a user input is given on the `input()` function.

You should see multiprocessing as a single processing line handling multiple processes at the same time without waiting for any of those processes' long tasks to finish. On the other hand, threading is like having various processing lines each at its own speed that allows waiting for individual processing tasks to finish.

Because you were using multiprocessing, the `while True` loop and the `input()` function were colliding and python responded with a EOF (End Of File) error in the `input()` process. You should adjust your code as follows:

```py
import os
from threading import Thread
from os import listdir
import simple_chalk as chk

path = "./QuickiPies"
pathBoolean = os.path.exists(path)
quickiPy = "null"


def checkPath():
    if pathBoolean == False:
        os.mkdir(path)

    takeQuickiPy()


def takeQuickiPy():
    print(chk.greenBright.bold(
        "Welcome to NotiPy! By pressing Ctrl+Shift+S your QuickiPy will be saved to the QuickiPy directory. Open an existing QuickiPy with Ctrl+Shift+O."))
    quickiPy = input(">    ")


def checkShortcut():
    while True:
        if kd.is_pressed("ctrl+shift+o"):
            listDir()
            break
        elif kd.is_pressed("ctrl+shift+s"):
            saveQuickiPy()
            break


def listDir():
    print("Choose your QuickiPy:")
    for i in listdir(path):
        print(i)


def saveQuickiPy():
    file = open(path + "/" + "note.txt", "w")
    file.write(quickiPy)
    file.close()
    print(chk.greenBright.bold("QuickiPy saved!"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    process1 = Thread(target=checkPath)
    jobs.append(process1)
    process2 = Thread(target=checkShortcut)
    jobs.append(process2)
    process1.start()
    process2.start()
```