# EOF error while taking input using multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, eoferror

I am making a stop watch in python which prints out the seconds passed and as soon as the user presses enter, it stops.
I am using multiprocessing to ask for an input and keep printing until an input is received. but the code is giving an EOF error for the input statement when I run it, what am I doing wrong?

```
import os
import multiprocessing 


end = multiprocessing.Value('i',0)

def get_input(end):
    x = input('')
    end.value = 1


def print_time(end):
    secs = 0
    mins = 0
    hrs = 0 

    x = input('start: ')

    while True:
        mins, secs = divmod(secs, 60)
        hrs = 0 
        if mins > 60:
            hrs, mins = divmod(mins, 60)
        timer_display = '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(hrs, mins, secs)
        print(timer_display)

        if end.value == 1:
            break
        time.sleep(1)

        secs += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    func1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = get_input, args = (end,))
    func2 = multiprocessing.Process(target = print_time, args = (end,))


    func1.start()
    func2.start()

    func1.join()
    func2.join()
```

Comment: Both processes will be reading from stdin at the same time. Also, your "stopwatch" will not be accurate. It will drift

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to use input when multiprocessing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47141057/unable-to-use-input-when-multiprocessing-in-python)

Comment: You cannot use `input` in a subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to start/stop the stopwatch in the main program and just use one Process to display the timer. Something like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value
import time

def showTime(end):
    start = time.time()

    while end.value == 0:
        elapsed = int(time.time() - start)
        ss = elapsed % 60
        mm = elapsed // 60 % 60
        hh = elapsed // 3600
        print(f'{hh:02d}:{mm:02d}:{ss:02d}')
        time.sleep(1)
        


def main():
    input('Press enter to start: ')
    end = Value('i', 0)
    Process(target=showTime, args=(end,)).start()
    input('Press enter to stop: ')
    end.value = 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Also, this technique allows for any potential drift due to processing time