# Reading a PDF Portfolio in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf

I have a pdf portfolio which is comprised of an email thread, each email containing attachments. I would like to read the text from each email and extract the attachments. However, I cannot find information on how to read a pdf portfolio in python. I have tried using the libraries, PDFMiner and textract, but the output simply reads, "For the best experience, open this PDF portfolio in Acrobat X or Adobe Reader X, or later. Get Adobe Reader Now!"

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The program `pdfdetach` from the [poppler](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/) utilities can extract attachments.

Most UNIX-like operating system distributions have a `poppler-utils` package available. You can find a ms-windows version on SourceForge.

You can use the `subprocess` module to call this program from Python.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `python-poppler`.

```
from poppler import load_from_file

pdf_document = load_from_file("portfolio.pdf")

if pdf_document.has_embedded_files():
    for attachment in pdf_document.embedded_files():
        print(attachment.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me quite a bit of work to extract the embedded files from a portfolio using @Roland Smith and @ikreb answers.  python-poppler has a fairly cryptic API and the instructions above just get the data, not the pdf.  The following steps detail how to get the documents out of a portfolio using poppler and python subprocess:

1. You will need poppler installed.  It can be installed with homebrew (or condo) on a Mac.  You might also need cmake (also installed with homebrew).  Here are various ways to install on Windows:  [How to install Poppler on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381713/how-to-install-poppler-on-windows)
2. Poppler is a command line program so you don't necessarily have to use python to solve your problem.  From command line:

```
# this will pull the files from the portfolio and save them to the same directory
pdfdetach -saveall <file_name, no quotes>

# example:
pdfdetach -saveall my_portfolio.pdf
```

3. Within python, use subprocess as follows:

```
import subprocess

# pdfdetach will save all files from the portfolio to the same directory
subprocess.run(['pdfdetach', '-saveall', file_name.pdf])

# if you want to get a list of the files, use -list (see note below)
subprocess.run(['pdfdetach', '-list', file_name])

# it is also useful, within a script, to save to another folder using -o:
subprocess.run(['pdfdetach', '-saveall', os.path.join(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), my_portfolio.pdf), '-o', os.path.join(os.getcwd(), './out')])
```

note on list output:  the output will be a subprocess object that must be parsed to make a python list of file names.  This post has several ways to do that: [python subprocess output to list or file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880461/python-subprocess-output-to-list-or-file/8880539)