# Reading PDF portfolio in R

Tags: r, pdf, pdftools

Is it possible to read/convert PDF portfolios in R?

I usually use `pdftools`, however, I get an error:

```r
library(pdftools)
#> Using poppler version 0.73.0

link <- c("http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/cdrh_docs/pdf19/K190072.pdf")

pdftools::pdf_convert(link, dpi = 600)
#> Converting page 1 to K190072_1.png...
#> PDF error: Non conformant codestream TPsot==TNsot.<0a>
#> PDF error: Non conformant codestream TPsot==TNsot.<0a>
#> PDF error: Non conformant codestream TPsot==TNsot.<0a>
#> PDF error: Non conformant codestream TPsot==TNsot.<0a>
#>  done!
#> [1] "K190072_1.png"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

The `K190072_1.png` I finally get is only the image of the portfolio front page.

I am interessted in the document `K190072.510kSummary.Final_Sent001.pdf` of this PDF portfolio

I found a way for Python ([Reading a PDF Portfolio in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41596787/reading-a-pdf-portfolio-in-python)) but I would really like to do that in R.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with `pdf_convert` handling one-page raw pdf data (it wants to use `basename(pdf)` under these conditions), so I have edited that function so that it also works with the second attached pdf file.

If you only need the first file then you could run this with the original `pdf_convert` function, but it will give an error with the second file.

If you are interested in rendering raster graphics from the attached files this worked for me:

```r
library(pdftools)
#> Using poppler version 21.02.0
link <- c("http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/cdrh_docs/pdf19/K190072.pdf")

pdf_convert <- function (pdf, format = "png", pages = NULL, filenames = NULL, 
          dpi = 72, antialias = TRUE, opw = "", upw = "", verbose = TRUE) {
    config <- poppler_config()
    if (!config$can_render || !length(config$supported_image_formats)) 
        stop("You version of libppoppler does not support rendering")
    format <- match.arg(format, poppler_config()$supported_image_formats)
    if (is.null(pages)) 
        pages <- seq_len(pdf_info(pdf, opw = opw, upw = upw)$pages)
    if (!is.numeric(pages) || !length(pages)) 
        stop("Argument 'pages' must be a one-indexed vector of page numbers")
    if (length(filenames) < 2 & !is.raw(pdf)) {   # added !is.raw(pdf)
        input <- sub(".pdf", "", basename(pdf), fixed = TRUE)
        filenames <- if (length(filenames)) {
            sprintf(filenames, pages, format)
        }
        else {
            sprintf("%s_%d.%s", input, pages, format)
        }
    }
    if (length(filenames) != length(pages)) 
        stop("Length of 'filenames' must be one or equal to 'pages'")
    antialiasing <- isTRUE(antialias) || isTRUE(antialias == 
                                                    "draw")
    text_antialiasing <- isTRUE(antialias) || isTRUE(antialias == 
                                                         "text")
    pdftools:::poppler_convert(pdftools:::loadfile(pdf), format, pages, filenames, 
                    dpi, opw, upw, antialiasing, text_antialiasing, verbose)
}

lapply(pdf_attachments(link), function(x) pdf_convert(x$data, 
    filenames=paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(x$name), "-", 
                     seq_along(pdf_data(x$data)), ".png")))
#> Converting page 1 to K190072.510kSummary.Final_Sent001-1.png... done!
#> Converting page 2 to K190072.510kSummary.Final_Sent001-2.png... done!
#> Converting page 3 to K190072.510kSummary.Final_Sent001-3.png... done!
#> Converting page 4 to K190072.510kSummary.Final_Sent001-4.png... done!
#> Converting page 5 to K190072.510kSummary.Final_Sent001-5.png... done!
#> Converting page 1 to K190072.IFU.FINAL_Sent001-1.png... done!
#> Converting page 1 to K190072.Letter.SE.FINAL_Sent001-1.png... done!
#> Converting page 2 to K190072.Letter.SE.FINAL_Sent001-2.png... done!
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "K190072.510kSummary.Final_Sent001-1.png"
#> [2] "K190072.510kSummary.Final_Sent001-2.png"
#> [3] "K190072.510kSummary.Final_Sent001-3.png"
#> [4] "K190072.510kSummary.Final_Sent001-4.png"
#> [5] "K190072.510kSummary.Final_Sent001-5.png"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "K190072.IFU.FINAL_Sent001-1.png"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "K190072.Letter.SE.FINAL_Sent001-1.png"
#> [2] "K190072.Letter.SE.FINAL_Sent001-2.png"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>