# Python subprocess hangs if trying to read its output

Tags: python, subprocess

I have this little utility function that I use to execute external processes. In some cases, it hangs when I try to read the output of the process. Commenting out the output reading lines, it works.

```
def execute(command, cwd):
    command = command.split(' ')
    process = Popen(command,
        stderr=STDOUT, stdout=PIPE,
        cwd = cwd)

    # WITHOUT THIS IT WORKS
    #for line in process.stdout:    
    #    log.info('executing %s for user %s: %s' % (command, user.username, line))

    # ANOTHER TRY AT READING THE OUTPUT. ALSO MAKES IT HANG
    #output = p.communicate()[0]
    #log.info('executing %s for user %s: %s' % (command, user.username, output))

    process.wait()
```

Any help? I need to output for debugging purpose.

Comment: What is the command you are trying to execute? Also, to parse a command, use `shlex.split(command)` to ensure handling of quotes and such.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804543/read-subprocess-stdout-line-by-line

Answer (score 2):

I started using [async_subprocess](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/440554-module-to-allow-asynchronous-subprocess-use-on-win/) years ago and never looked back. It's also available from PyPI [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/async_subprocess/0.2.1).