# Python Popen to read live output (linux)

Tags: python, parsing, popen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [read subprocess stdout line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804543/read-subprocess-stdout-line-by-line)

I wrote a C++ program that generates all bunch of text in the Linux console.

I am using a python script to parse the output of this C++. I am doing this like that:

```
cmd = ["./starter"] 

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

for line in p.stdout:

    strLine = str(line).rstrip()
    print(">>> " + strLine )
```

This is working. BUT i have a major problem, the output is not live. I mean by that, that after starting the script nothing is printed out, but only after couple second things are coming out.. It is almost like python is waiting a number of character max to then print them all at once...

Is there a way to tell python to print a line AS SOON AS it was printed by the C++ program ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `stdout` file as an iterator, and that uses a largish buffer, delaying your prints. Use `.readline()` instead; you can still make that into a loop using `iter()` with a sentinel:

```
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
    strLine = str(line).rstrip()
    print(">>> " + strLine )
```

You can also add `flush=True` to your print function call:

```
print(">>> " + strLine, flush=True)
```

or, if you are on Python 2 instead of Python 3 (where `print` is a statement, not a function), you can directly flush the `stdout` buffer:

```
import sys

sys.stdout.flush()
```

By default, `stdout` is line-buffered, so python normally should flush the buffer whenever you print a newline.

Comment: By adding flush it does the same thing

Comment: Then your C++ program output is buffered too.

Comment: @Johny19: Ah, no, I see what else is wrong. Updated.

Comment: I also used fflush(stdout) in my C++. But even without it the output in the console when starting the C++ directly is fast and fluid

Comment: @Johny19: Yup, already updated the answer; there is a read buffer involved when iterating over `p.stdout` that you need to avoid.