# Getting return information from another python script

Tags: python, linux

I'm on linux, and I have one python script that I want to call from another python script. I don't want to import it as a module (for a layer of security, and now for an academic exercise because I want to figure this out), I want to actually have one script call the other with os.system() or another function like that, and have the other script return a list of tuples to the first script.

I know this might not be the optimal way to do it, but I'd like to try it out, and learn some stuff in the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Importing a module is different from executing it as a script. If you don't trust the child Python script; you shouldn't run any code from it.

A regular way to use some code from another Python module:

```
import another_module

result = another_module.some_function(args)
```

If you want to execute it instead of importing:

```
namespace = {'args': [1,2,3]} # define __name__, __file__ if necessary
execfile('some_script.py', namespace)
result = namespace['result']
```

[`execfile()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile) is used very rarely in Python. It might be useful in a debugger, a profiler, or to run `setup.py` in tools such as `pip`, `easy_install`.

See also [`runpy` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/runpy.html).

If another script is executed in a different process; you could use many [IPC methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). The simplest way is just pipe serialized (Python objects converted to a bytestring) input args into subprocess' stdin and read the result back from its stdout as [suggested by @kirelagin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16877343/4279):

```
import json
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

marshal, unmarshal = json.dumps, json.loads

p = Popen([sys.executable, 'some_script.py'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
result = unmarshal(p.communicate(marshal(args))[0])
```

where `some_script.py` could be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
import sys

args = json.load(sys.stdin)   # read input data from stdin
result = [x*x for x in args]  # compute result
json.dump(result, sys.stdout) # write result to stdout
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up piping it, but because the data-size was acceptably small and easy to model as a string, I didn't need to serialize it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html):

```
subprocess.call(["python", "myscript.py"])
```

This will also return the process return value (such as 0 or 1).

Answer (score 2):

You will need some kind of serialization to return a list. I'd suggest [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) or [JSON](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Your other script will print it to `stdout` and the calling script will read it back and deserialize.

Comment: So basically turn the data into a large int, return that code, and then reverse it? How long can a system code return be?

Comment: @Nathan No-no, turn it into a string and write to `stdout`. Then your calling script will read it through a pipe (check `subprocess.Popen` documentation).

Comment: Is this secure? Would stout somehow be able to be intercepted? 

Could you give me an example of doing this? Say I have a.py and b.py, how would I go about this process?

Comment: Now, it's not secure at all. Any communication with another process is not secure. I don't have an example, why don't you just try it? In `a.py` you call `pickle` and `print` the resulting string. In `b.py` you use `Subprocess.Popen` to execute `a.py` and read its `stdout`. An example of reading `subprocess` `stdout` can be found, for example, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804543/read-subprocess-stdout-line-by-line

Comment: Okay, I'll check it out. Thanks! 

"Any communication with another process is not secure" are you sure that's accurate? There must be some underlying security for process interaction at the os level.

Comment: It depends on your definition of “secure communication”. Define it and I'll give you a more accurate statement ;). For example root can do _anything_. _Absoultely anything_, so you just can't be secure.

Comment: Fair enough. By the way, it worked! I ended up just piping stdout instead of serializing though, because the data size wasn't large. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Nathan Well, you can only wright text to stdout and list is a list, not text. Serialization is a process of converting an object to a string so that it can be passed over network or a stream. You can't just write a list. Of course you can cast it to a string and then restore with `eval` but that's not really cool.

Comment: I was able to format it so it worked, ended up just passing a null delimited string, then I split it into a list. :)

Comment: Yeah, that's what they call “reinventing the wheel”. Was that really simpler than calling `json.dumps` (or `pickle.dumps`) in the first script and `json.loads` (or `pickle.loads`) in the second one?

Comment: Reinventing the wheel is quite fun :) and dumping pickle made it available as a shared resource to all python scripts, whereas the way I did it just accesses the local stdin/stdout

Answer (score 1):

You know, [ZMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) is very useful for inter proces communication. You can well use it with json objects.

Here is the [python binding](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings%3apython)

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple.

```
import popen2
fout, fin = popen2.popen2('python your_python_script.py')
data = fout.readline().strip()
if data <> '':
    # you have your `data`, so do something with it
```

Comment: Yeah, and don't forget `from __future__ import barry_as_FLUFL` ;).