# How do I make a python program give a command to a command shell?

Tags: python, windows, shell, ipc

How do I make a python program text pass as input to another process? Specifically a command shell, not command line!

Not run as

```
example.exe --doSomething -i random.txt -o random1.txt
```

but as

```
example.exe
# example shell loading
# and then in loaded shell
> doSomething -i random.txt -o random1.txt
```

EDITED POST:

How do I make a python program pass input to another window at the command line? I want to do this:

```
something = raw_input('Waddaya wanna do?')
if something == 'Halt!':
        placeholder('exit')
if something == 'Get help!':
        placeholder('help %COMMAND%')
```

placeholder() stands for the command which will pass what is in the brackets to the command shell. I. E. if processname = java.exe, it would pass 'exit' to 'java.exe.'

Comment: Oh, by the way, the command line shell is java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use a Python program to input text to a Java command prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887408/use-a-python-program-to-input-text-to-a-java-command-prompt)

Comment: Please don't repost your own questions.

Comment: @Hyperboreus this one is better, it's clearer what OP wants

Comment: That one is more of a duplicate (not clear enough) so I deleted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're seeking for `subprocess.popen`, see an example in a [tutorial](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_subprocess_module.php):

> Writing to a process can be done in a very similar way. If we want to send data to the process's stdin, we need to create the Popen object with stdin=subprocess.PIPE.
>   To test it let's write another program (write_to_stdin.py) which simply prints Received: and then repeats the message we send it:
>
> ```
> # write_to_stdin.py
> import sys
> input = sys.stdin.read()
> sys.stdout.write('Received: %s'%input)
> ```
>
> To send a message to stdin, we pass the string we want to send as the input argument to communicate():
>
> ```
> >>> proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'write_to_stdin.py'],  stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
> >>> proc.communicate('Hello?')
> Received: Hello?(None, None)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The basic gist is you want to use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) and pass in the stdin argument and the stdout and stderr arguments as PIPE.

```
 p = subprocess.Popen(args, *,
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                      stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This allows you to use p to send and receive messages to the subprocess:

```
p.stdin.write('Some input\n')
...
x = p.stdout.readline()
...
```

Here are some good examples:

[read subprocess stdout line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804543/read-subprocess-stdout-line-by-line)

[Python - How do I pass a string into subprocess.Popen (using the stdin argument)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542/python-how-do-i-pass-a-string-into-subprocess-popen-using-the-stdin-argument)