# Python: Printing file to stream as file changes

Tags: python, stdout, maya

I am running a large suite of unittests in a subprocess through another application (Autodesk Maya). Maya runs a special Python interpreter with it's own libraries that cannot be used outside of the application, thus the need to test within the application. I would like the parent process to print the results of the testing as it is happening.  The subprocess is very 'noisy' though, so I do not want to simply redirect the subprocess's stdout to the parent process's stdout.  Instead, I would like the test runner to somehow directly stream to the parent process's stdout

I am currently using a TextTestRunner in the subprocess with it's stdout set to an open file.  The parent process knows where this file exists, and writes the contents of the tile to stdout once the subprocess is complete.  Since the tests can take a long time to run though, I would prefer that the parent process can somehow 'stream' the contents of this file as it is being created by the subprocess.  But I am not sure how to do this or if there is a better approach.

Here's an example of how this is currently set up.

```
module_path = 'my.test.module'
suite_callable = 'suite'
stream_fpath = '/tmp/the_test_results.txt'
script_fpath = '/tmp/the_test_script.py'
script = '''
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] <= 2 and sys.version_info[1] <= 6:
    import unittest2 as unittest
else:
    import unittest

import {module_path}
suite = {module_path}.{suite_callable}()
with open("{stream_path}", "w") as output:
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(stream=output)
    runner.run(suite)
    output.close()

'''.format(**locals())

with open(script_fpath, 'w') as f:
    f.write(script)
subprocess.call(['maya', '-command', '\'python("execfile(\\"{script_fpath}\\")")\''.format(**locals())]
with open(stream_fpath, 'r') as f:
    print f.read()
```

Thanks for any info!

Comment: related: [read subprocess stdout line by line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2804543/4279)

Comment: Do you actually run the Maya application to do this? unless you're testing GUI elements, it's usually easier to run tests in mayapy.exe and use maya.standalone when you need the actual Maya api

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; unfortunately, for various reasons I cannot use mayapy at my facility.  We have a pretty specific bootstrap that doesn't work with mayapy.  For this and other technical reasons, our official policy is that we do not support *anything* that relies upon it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than writing to a file, you shoud be able to make a [file-like object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) to replace stderr.  The object's write method could do something with each input as it comes in; you could squirt it to something listening on TCP, or print stuff to a TK window, or anything else in addition to logging to a file if you still want the results.

Implementing a stream replacement is pretty simple, in this case you probably only need to implement write, writelines, open and close (unless your testrunner also uses flush).

```
class FakeStdErr(object):
     def __init__(self)
         self.lines = []

     def write(self, text):
         self.lines.append(text)

    def writelines(self, *args):
         for item in args: self.lines.append(item)

    def open(self):
        self.lines = []

    def close (self):
        pass
```

In your use case you might want to use a [silencer class](http://techartsurvival.blogspot.com/2014/01/the-sounds-of-python-silence.html) (which is a variant on the same trick) to replace the default stdout (to shut up your chatty process) and direct your test runner stream to this guy; after all the tests are done you could dump the contents to disk as a file or print them to the screen by restoring the default stdout (the link shows how to do that if you're not familiar).

Comment: Thanks - this ended up being the approach I went with.  I set up a TCP server running in my parent process, and made a file-like object in the child process that sends messages to the server.  I passed this object to the TextTestRunner.  The server hands these back sys.stdout.

Answer (score 0):

(Edited - suggest using stderr, or parsing)

Alternative 1: Intercept the output rather than having it go to a file.

Have `script` write to `sys.stderr` instead of the `open()` of `stream_fpath`:

```
runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(stream=sys.stderr)
```

Replace `subprocess.call` with `running = subprocess.Popen(<existing parameters>, stderr=PIPE)`.  Then read `running.stderr` until EOF or until `running.poll()` returns other than `None`.  You can do what you want with the data.  For example, you can print it to the screen and also print it to `stream_fpath`.

This assumes that the noisy output comes from `maya`, which will still be dumping to `stdout`.

Alternative 2: parse the noisy output from `stdout=PIPE`.  If you can differentiate the test runner's output by adding some tag to each line, you can search for that tag and only print the lines that match.

[Popen documentation (Python 2)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)

Comment: The problem with this is that my subprocess is noisy, and I do not want to capture all stdout as mentioned above.  I specifically want to capture the output from the test runner and ignore the rest of the application's output.

Comment: @WoadieStyol - sorry I missed that.  See edited answer.