# Non blocking output streaming with python subprocess Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, popen

I would like to know if there is any way to handle the case of non blocking as well as streaming the `stdout` and `stderr` from a python subprocess. I have gone through couple of articles over this website, but none has an answer to this scenario. It either shows by running the read in another thread, so that the main thread is left unaffected (or) just how to stream the data from the process. My issue is a combination of both. I guess the problem is at the place of `read()` or `readline()` as they are blocking one way or the other during the output streaming.

I want to have a streamable object that's my main concern. I am attaching the references I have been through for further reference.

```
script_process = subprocess.Popen(command_sequence[i],preexec_fn=os.setsid, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    while script_process.poll() is None:
       for output in iter(lambda: script_process.stdout.readline(), b''):
           sys.stdout.writelines(output)
```

[Non-blocking read on a subprocess.PIPE in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python)

[Reliable non blocking reads from subprocess stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22044253/reliable-non-blocking-reads-from-subprocess-stdout)

[printing stdout in realtime from a subprocess that requires stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411966/printing-stdout-in-realtime-from-a-subprocess-that-requires-stdin)

[Constantly print Subprocess output while process is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417546/constantly-print-subprocess-output-while-process-is-running)

[Is it possible to stream output from a python subprocess to a webpage in real time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22423906/is-it-possible-to-stream-output-from-a-python-subprocess-to-a-webpage-in-real-ti)

[How to create non-blocking continuous reading from `stdin`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217916/how-to-create-non-blocking-continuous-reading-from-stdin)

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible piece of code?

Comment: @ManishDash I have added a small piece of code with which you can reproduce it. Especially when the command sequence has some print in a callback, it never prints.

Comment: Hi @saikishor, did you get any working solution on that? All the internets don't seem to have a working, cross-os solution for real-time, line-by-line stdout capture in Python3.

Comment: I figured out that it is easier to write it down to a tempfile and reading it time to time to find the difference in the content.