# Stop sys.stdout from writing to a text file

Tags: python, spyder, sys

I am using python sys to save my stdout to a text file.

```
sys.stdout=open('OLSYield.txt','w')
```

However I only want a portion of the stdout to go to the text. How do I stop writing to txt file and redirect back to the terminal or console?

So it should look something like

```
sys.stdout=open('OLSYield.txt','w')
print "helloWorld appears in text file"

sys.stdout=close('OLSYield.txt','w')
print "helloWorld appears in console"
```

Im not sure what command I should use to close `stdout=open`

Comment: `.stdout` will read the whole thing - do you mean to use `.stdout.readline()` instead?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804543/read-subprocess-stdout-line-by-line#answer-2813530

Comment: @MacroMan: You can't use `readline` on stdout.

Answer (score 6):

to change the output back to the console you need to keep a reference to the original stdout:

```
orig_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout=open('OLSYield.txt','w')
print "helloWorld appears in text file"

sys.stdout.close()
sys.stdout=orig_stdout 
print "helloWorld appears in console"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stop writing to your file and revert to the console like this:

```
sys.stdout = open("file.txt", "w")
print "in file"

sys.stdout.close()
sys.stdout = open("/dev/stdout", "w")

print "in console"
```

Comment: the problem with this solution is that it's platform specific, so it doesn't work on windows

Comment: You're 100% right. As soon as I read your answer I thought that. On the other hand, if you're running in some env (e.g. CI?) and your original stdout isn't what you want, you're also stuck.

Comment: Meh. No. Reverting to original stdout seems cleanest/safer

Comment: i figure its the most predicable way of doing it as it will resume the previous behavior, I know I've done things where i redirect the output for logging/debugging purposes, my method above would at least resume that.

Comment: Yeah especially if you're running in some container/application or other cross platform situation.