# returncode of Popen object is None after the process is terminated

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm running a process with the use of `Popen`. I need to wait for the process to terminate. I'm checking that the process have terminated through the `returncode`. When `returncode` is different from `None` the process must have terminated. The problem is that when `print_output` is `False` the `returncode` is always `None`, even when the process have finished running (terminated). This is however not the case when `print_output` is `True`. I'm using the following code to run the process:

```
def run(command, print_output=True):
    # code mostly from: http://sharats.me/the-ever-useful-and-neat-subprocess-module.html
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
    from threading import Thread
    from queue import Queue, Empty
    from time import sleep

    io_q = Queue()

    def stream_watcher(identifier, stream):
        for line in stream:
            io_q.put((identifier, line))

        if not stream.closed:
            stream.close()

    with Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True) as proc:
        if print_output:

            Thread(target=stream_watcher, name='stdout-watcher', args=('STDOUT', proc.stdout)).start()
            Thread(target=stream_watcher, name='stderr-watcher', args=('STDERR', proc.stderr)).start()

            def printer():
                while True:
                    try:
                        # Block for 1 second.
                        item = io_q.get(True, 1)
                    except Empty:
                        # No output in either streams for a second. Are we done?
                        if proc.poll() is not None:
                            break
                    else:
                        identifier, line = item
                        print(identifier + ':', line, end='')

            Thread(target=printer, name='printer').start()

        while proc.returncode is None:
            sleep(2)
            proc.poll()

        if not proc.returncode == 0:
            raise RuntimeError(
                'The process call "{}" returned with code {}. The return code is not 0, thus an error '
                'occurred.'.format(list(command), proc.returncode))

        return proc.stdout, proc.stderr
```

Any clues to what might cause this problem?

EDIT: Discovered something pretty weird. I'm running the following code:

```
run(my_command, True)
print('--------done--------')
run(my_command, False)
print('--------done--------')
```

`'--------done--------'` is never printed even though `run(my_command, False)` gets executed.

Comment: Can anybody reproduce any of these problems?

Comment: The issue is that the below suggested `popen.wait()` doesn't work for the above use case. But I found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57093927/9801061

Answer (score 23):

### TL;DR

add `popen.wait()` after `subprocess.Popen()`

### Explanation Part (sort of)

Python goes too fast and the child process is ended but returncode can't be read

(I don't really know why it does that. Explanations welcome)

#### Why did I use this:

Shell command execution and get **both** return code and output (stdout)

```
def exec_cmd(cmd):
    pop = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    pop.wait()
    return [pop.returncode, pop.communicate()[0]]
```

Also: please read the `.wait` warning on the [popen page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait)

Comment: Unfortunately, .wait cannot be used with PIPE. Any alternative idea?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why it did not work, but I think it has something to do with not closing the streams. The following code works:

```
def run(command, print_output=True):
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
    from io import StringIO

    popen = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
    out = StringIO()
    for line in popen.stdout:
        if print_output:
            print(line, end='')
        else:
            out.write(line)

    popen.stdout.close()
    return_code = popen.wait()

    if not return_code == 0:
        raise RuntimeError(
            'The process call "{}" returned with code {}. The return code is not 0, thus an error '
            'occurred.'.format(list(command), return_code))

    stdout_string = out.getvalue()
    out.close()

    return stdout_string
```

Comment: I just had to add `popen.wait()` just below after my `subprocess.Popen(...)`

Comment: @Boop's comment should be in the answer in my opinion. Or should be the answer.