# How to integrate Java and Python?

Tags: java, python

I am trying something out combining java and python for some encryption reasons where the encryption code is actually a java file from the provider but I am writing a python code. So what I want is to execute the encryption code on java using

```
x = os.system("java file.java")
```

and just return the value from the java execution like in a function

```
print x
```

Like this:

**java_hello_world.py**

```
import os

x = os.system("java HelloWorld")
print x # This should print HELLO WORLD
```

**HelloWorld.java**

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x;
        x = "Hello World";
        System.out.println(x);
        return "HELLO WORLD";
    }

}
```

The java file above by the way returns an error:

```
HelloWorld.java:7: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
return x;
```

**PS**

I am not a Java Developer, I have zero experience

Any suggested method will be great as long as I have my desired result in python

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args)` - note the `void`. You can't return a value from the main method.

Comment: Dude... did you even try googling? Your problem is that "main" method has return type "void" (so, basically "no return") and yet you're returning something...

Comment: So any idea, how will I get the result that I want?

Comment: Oh, you have a lot of learning to do!

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, I don't really know how to code Java and I've never tried this cross language execution before

Comment: The simplest solution for you here and now may be to use Jython instead as your python engine as it can coexist with Java code.  I would, however, suggest you ask the provider if they have a working Python snippet you can build on.  You are currently looking at a lot of pain if you are not familar with Java.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, I could either subprocess or just convert the java code into a working python script or yes use Jython

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invoke another **process** there is no **returning** of values.

The only thing you could hope for is a **numerical** return code value.

What you are actually looking for is this:

- the program that runs in that process writes to either *stdout* ... or to some file
- your python code that triggered that process can then *read* that content

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804543/read-subprocess-stdout-line-by-line) for instructions how your python script can read what a *subprocess* is writing its stdout.

And for the record: there are no detours. If you intend to do anything "serious" with your java code, then you have to **learn** enough Java to make that happen. Not understanding that a method that says *void* can't have a *return something* statement is a good example for that.

Same is true for the python side of things. Yes, *os.system()* is the simply, straight forward way to invoke some process. But if you do even a tiny bit of research on that subject, you might have seen that there is the *subprocess* module in python ... together with its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: can you suggest a code?

Comment: Thanks, I already did the subprocess

Answer (score 0):

Your main method can not return a value as it is declared `void`.

A process can only return a numeric exit code.

A way to communicate between different processes is [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)

Comment: So any idea, how will I get the result that I want?

Comment: That is a simple comment, but not an answer.