# Track error of subprocess and failures

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm maintaining a Perforce server via a Unix executable which logs the errors in the terminal whenever something happens to it. What I would like to do is use Python to start the executable, and then have it watch for any errors being logged in the terminal window from the application it's executing.

The following code works for execution, but I have no idea how to get data back from the subprocess when it gets logged to the terminal via some form of callback.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["./p4d"])
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually do it this way

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
proc = Popen(["./p4d"], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
out, err = pipe.communicate()
```

pipe.communicate() will hang until the process is finished and then returns stdout and stderr

Comment: Will this log errors as they occur, or just when the process exits?

Comment: You get all of the logs but only once the process ends. Reading stdout/stderr while the process is running is a little bit trickier.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804543/read-subprocess-stdout-line-by-line might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

`process.stdout` and `process.stdout` are file-like objects that you can read from. Assuming things are logged to stdout:

```
proc = Popen(['./p4d'], stdout=PIPE, encoding='utf-8')  # Or whatever encoding suits
for line in proc.stdout:
    # Note that line will end in `\n`, unless it is the last line.
    line = line.rstrip('\n')

    # Do something depending on the line
```