# Continuously capture output from subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, subprocess

I want to capture the output of a process called with

```
cmd = "doit input={input} conf={conf} output_dir={dir} gpu={gpu} --db-file .doit_gpu{gpu_id}.db".format(**kwargs)
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

continuously.
This process calls functions that print their result in the console as dictionary strings. E.g.:

```
{'subprocess_1': [<some data>]}
# then after some time
{'subprocess_2': [<some data>]}
# and some seconds later
{'subprocess_3': [<some data>]}
```

I want to be able to continuously capture the output and redirect it **immediately** to another dictionary that I initialized before.

```
process_table = {}
```

So this is how the dictionary would have to look like after the whole process finished:

```
process_table = {
    {'subprocess_1': [<some data>]},
    {'subprocess_2': [<some data>]},
    {'subprocess_3': [<some data>]}
}
```

The key point here (which is why I don't seem to find any related questions) is that `process_table` should be updated immediately after a subprocess finishes, not only after the entire process finished. This is why this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804543/read-subprocess-stdout-line-by-line) **is not enough**:

```
for line in process.stdout:
    print("this is the output:", line,)
```

Comment: So to be clear, you want your python script to block while waiting on each subprocess to finish, then gather the stdout of the process?

Comment: Yes. But as it prints to `stdout`, I want to capture the output and redirect it to the variable `process_table`. I use two threads, one running `process` and one reading `process_table` and doing some stuff with it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to my problem.
A simple

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

in the executed program (i.e. my *doit* script) printed the subprocess outputs immediately and I could save them to the `process_table` with

```
for line in process.stdout:
    subprocess_output = json.loads(line.decode("utf-8"))
    process_table.update(subprocess_output)
```