# Get duration of .wav from sox in python

Tags: python, audio, wav, sox

I know how to print the duration of the .wav file using sox at the Linux command.

```
soxi -D input.wav
```

So I used this syntax in python.

```
subprocess.call(['soxi', '-D', input.wav])
```

But I'd like to save the duration(seconds) in a variable.
How do I get it in a variable?

+++++++++++ edit ++++++++++++++

using)

```
wavduration = subprocess.call(['soxi', '-D', input.wav])
print(wavduration)
```

output)

```
4.000000
0
```

This is not the right way to do it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [read subprocess stdout line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804543/read-subprocess-stdout-line-by-line)

Answer (score 4):

Python has sox wrapper and it has following method.

```
seconds = sox.file_info.duration('input file name')
print(seconds)
```

docs
https://pysox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#module-sox.file_info

pysox
https://github.com/rabitt/pysox/blob/master/README.md