# Real time output of terminal command using subprocess module in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to display realtime data using subprocess module, But it only display first line only.
I tried to follow some of the tutorials. which are given here

[read subprocess stdout line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804543/read-subprocess-stdout-line-by-line)

Code i tried

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    ['aria2c', 'http://cdimage.deepin.com/releases/20Beta/deepin-20Beta-desktop-amd64.iso'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    # the real code does filtering here
    print("test:", line.rstrip())
```

Actual Output

[Display only one line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlOed.png)

Expected Output

[display all the informations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glti5.png)

Comment: `aria2c` is *also* writing to standard error, which you are not capturing.

Comment: Which operating system? On unix-like systems, the problem may be solved with a `pty` to make the program think it is running in a terminal.