# Execute cmd from python and get continuous output

Tags: python, bash, cmd

here is my problem: I need to execute a cmd command from python, the command is not something that executes fast, it will be running for a longer period of time. What I need is a way to #1 execute the command and #2 get the continuous output of that command.

Example of the output:

some text... (then about half a minute wait)
 some other text... (waiting for some time)
more text...

You get the idea, the output comes about every 30 seconds. I need to catch all of the outputs and do something with them. Is there a way to do this?

I know I can execute the command with os.system('command') but i'm struggling to find a way to read the output!

Comment: Look at the `subprocess` module. It's a bit of a steep learning curve, but doing what you want has more variations than you expect. `os.system()` has been deprecated for nearly 20 years (since Python 2.4), one of the reasons being the problem you have encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2813530/13267881).
In python 3 it would be something like:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen('./your_process', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    else: 
        # Do whathever you need to do with the last line written on 
        # stdout by your_process
        print("doing some stuff with...", line)
        print("done for this line!")
```

of course, you'd still need to take into account how the producer process buffers `stdout`, i.e. if the subprocess is something like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 10000000; i++) {
        printf("ping");
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

the consumer script will just read a lot of "ping"s all together (which can be resolved with a `fflush(stdout)` in the loop.)

A much more complicated solution can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4896288/13267881).