# Is there a way to get a callback in Python, whenever something gets printed to stdout in a thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, stdout

I want to monitor the stdout of a program and whenever it prints something into stdout, I want to get a callback in python to process the gathered data.

The program I want to monitor is not written in python, but behaves similar to this dummy_script.py:

```
import datetime
import random
import time

i = 0
while True:
    line = f"{datetime.datetime.now()} {i}"
    print(line)
    i += 1
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0, 1))
```

For the main python script I tried something like this:

```
from threading import Thread
import os


def do_stuff():
    command = f"python3 dummy_script.py"
    os.system(command)


thread = Thread(target=do_stuff)
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()
```

So is there a way to create a callback when a new line is printed to stdout?

Comment: Like this maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/2813530/2836621

Comment: [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) is blocking, you should use a non-blocking call instead, so `subprocess.Popen` like in the answer from Mark.