Printing subprocess stdout lines output
I created a simple Python function:
import subprocess
from io import TextIOWrapper


def run_shell_command(command: list, debug: bool = False):
    '''
    Run shell command

    :param command: Shell command
    :param debug: Debug mode
    :return: Result code and message
    '''
    try:
        process = subprocess.run(
            command, check=True, text=True, timeout=5,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
        )
        if debug:
            for line in TextIOWrapper(process.stdout, encoding='utf-8'):
                print(line)
        message = 'Shell command executed sucessfully'
        return ({'code': 200, 'msg': message, 'stdout': process.stdout})
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        return ({'code': 500, 'msg': e.output})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    command = run_shell_command(['ls', '-lah'], True)
    print(command)

When I run it in debug mode, I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/command.py", line 28, in <module>
    command = run_shell_command(['ls', '-lah'], True)
  File "/tmp/command.py", line 19, in run_shell_command
    for line in TextIOWrapper(process.stdout, encoding="utf-8"):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readable'

Running Python 3.9 on a Linux server, I was wondering if you can provide some insight where the issue might be. With debug disabled, I get a proper text output. Thank you for your help.
Edit: Based on the comments below, the fix is quite simple:
        if debug:
            print(process.stdout.rstrip())

However, IMO the accepted solution is better, compared to original code.

subprocess.run exits after the process ended. process.stdout contains the string output (not a pipe or file) of the command. A simple print(process.stdout) instead of the for-loop should print the whole output.

can you explain why you are passing process.stdout which is a str here (because you used text=True in subprocess.run) to TextIOWrapper but it doesn't accept a str. why are you using TextIOWrapper?

I think maybe you expected subprocess.run to return a Popen object, but it doesn't, it returns a CompletedProcess object

@juanpa.arrivillaga I was looking originally at this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34938743/14684366

@Floren right, you aren't working with a Popen object

Thank you @MichaelButscher, I edited the question with your simple fix.

@Floren That will only print out the output after the process is done, not "line by line".

@AKX, that is satisfactory for me, I will edit the question title. Thank you for letting me know.

Unfortunately "simple" doesn't cut it with all of the corner cases involved – you'll need to read the subprocess stdout as it's being streamed, print it out and accumulate it in a buffer, and keep track of time so you can timeout correctly. Note that this too has a possible bug (though not very dangerous) if the 4096 byte read happens to end at a multi-line character.
def run_shell_command(command: list, debug: bool = False, timeout: float = 5):
    """
    Run shell command

    :param command: Shell command
    :param debug: Debug mode
    :return: Result code and message
    """
    with subprocess.Popen(
        command,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    ) as process:
        start_time = time.time()
        output = b""
        while True:
            buf = process.stdout.read(4096)
            if debug:
                # could fail if `buf` happens to end in a multi-byte character
                print(buf.decode("utf-8", "ignore"))
            output += buf

            if time.time() - start_time > timeout:
                process.kill()
                message = "Shell command timed out"
                return {"code": 500, "msg": message, "stdout": output}

            if process.poll() is not None:
                break
    if process.returncode != 0:
        message = "Shell command failed"
        return {"code": 500, "msg": message, "stdout": output}

    message = "Shell command executed successfully"
    return {"code": 200, "msg": message, "stdout": output}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    command = run_shell_command(["ls", "-lah"], True)
    print(command)


The correct way to handle multi-byte characters split across chunk boundaries would be with an incremental decoder.

Absolutely. Or just keep accumulating more chunks until the string is decodable. But since this is just for debug output, I opted for keeping it a bit simpler.

Thank you @AKX for providing a solution to the original question. I will mark your answer as accepted solution, as is more complete.

@AKX, the linter returns this warning: "Consider using 'with' for resource-allocating operations." on subprocess.Popen. I was wondering what would be code alternative to fix this?

@Floren Sure – augmented the answer to use with for resource management.

Thanks you @AKX, there is something interesting, while running a git clone or git branch command. Not the entire output is printed, I was wondering what is the root cause?

What's missing?

If I run a git clone repo someurl it will not show the actual cloning output, I think this is how github works.

Right, that's presumably git just doing a different thing depending on if it's connected to a TTY device (and if you're redirecting output, it's not). See git clone --progress maybe?

That fixed the issue, thank you!
