# How to print the output of shell instantly by python script

Tags: python

I executed some commands in shell with python. I need to show the command response in shell.  But the commands will execute 10s . I need to wait. How can I show the echo of the commands instantly. Following is my code

```
cmd = "commands"
output = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(output.stdout.read())
```

And I need to use the output of the command. so I can't use `subprocess.call`

Comment: If you don't use the output of the command: `subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)`

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to ues the output of the command

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asynchronously read stdout from subprocess.Popen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822237/asynchronously-read-stdout-from-subprocess-popen)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read from `output.stdout` in a loop:

```
cmd = "commands"
output = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in output.stdout:
    print(line)
```

edit: seems then in python2 this still doesn't work in evey case, but this will:

```
for line in iter(output.stdout.readline, ''):
    print(line)
```